# How to undelete a file previously deleted in git's history?

Tags: git, repository, history, undelete

Using [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147097/how-to-prepend-the-past-to-a-git-repository/3148117#3148117) on another question I could prepend a snapshot-history to my git repository. Since one of the files is not part of my history but only in the snapshots, the first original commit now also contains the deletion of this file. How can I undo that?

*At first I thought this was the opposite of [How do I remove sensitive files from git’s history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history), but actually I don't want to insert a file into history but just remove the deletion from history.*

Comment: Git does not track intention, only content. If the file exists in an ancestor and is removed in a child commit, then “remove the deletion from history” and “re-insert the into history” amount to the same thing: make sure the file shows up in the child and its children.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I got it:

```
git tag originalHead # just in case
git rebase -i <id of the parent of the commit that deleted the file>
# change pick to edit for that commit
git checkout <id of the previous commit> <filename> # thanks for reminding, kubi
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
git tag -d originalHead
```

**edit** unfortunately this will leave all tags at the old timeline, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150685/can-tags-be-automatically-moved-after-a-git-filter-branch-and-rebase)

Comment: Seriously!
git rebase -i <id of the parent of the commit that deleted the file>
This saved my life

Comment: What does it mean/what are the consequences of leaving all tags at the old timeline?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Your log won't show them at the "proper" commits (also for `git describe`) and the originally tagged ones won't ever be removed by `git clean`. Using `git diff` (or any command actually) with tags will not compare the proper commits as well. Basically everything you do involving history will use the "wrong" commits in a way

Answer (score 73):

```
git checkout <commit> <filename>
```

Comment: thanks, but that only restores it. I want history to look as if the file was never removed