# Can tags be automatically moved after a git filter-branch and rebase?

Tags: git, history, tags, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

**edit** The question boils down to "Can `git rebase` be instructed to rebase tags, too?" But an answer to the original question would also help.

---

Asking [How to prepend the past to a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147097/how-to-prepend-the-past-to-a-git-repository) I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147097/how-to-prepend-the-past-to-a-git-repository/3148117#3148117). <**edit**>Then I rebased to include a file that was only in the snapshots, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150394/how-to-undelete-a-file-previously-deleted-in-gits-history/3150528#3150528).<**/edit**> Since history was rewritten (by `git filter-branch` or `git rebase` or both?) all tags are still on the original time line* and I'd somehow like to move them to the new one. I think I made all commit-messages with tags unique so I could try writing a script that uses them, but a more general `git move-tags <from> <to>` would be better.

So, is there a way to address "the commit which is N commits after  on the new timeline such that the Nth commit after  on the old timeline is tagged "? Any other solution except the obvious manual retagging would also be great.

*(please feel free to correct that horribly long sentence into plain English...)*

*) *hey, git solved the grandfather-paradox!*

Comment: The title says “rebase” but the body talks about “filter-branch”, did you do both (as hinted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150394/how-to-undelete-a-file-previously-deleted-in-gits-history/3150528#3150528))? With `--tag-name-filter`, filter-branch can rewrite tags, but this will not help if there is a subsequent rebase involved.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I fixed that. Yes, I used `git rebase` after the graft+filter-branch. The tags are fine after the latter, and I should have remembered that rebasing creates a separate branch leaving the original tags intact. So the basic question is "Can `git rebase` be instructed to rebase tags, too?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’ve written a script that does this.

```
$ git-rebase-tags master
Rebasing 107 tags onto 'master'
Can't rebase tag 'staging-deploy-01' because there are no identical commits on 'master'
Pointed tag 'v0.0.11' at commit 81e16f2ca1bc7802547bf19c1dba1a68212eafff
Pointed tag 'v0.0.12' at commit 17051cc28084dd56ae56e96767bceee46217c02d
Pointed tag 'v0.0.13' at commit 5d795076ba4b33f81d327dcf9bff727cef7771a2
[...]
```

See [gist.github.com/908381](http://gist.github.com/908381).

But even better, use the `--tag-name-filter` option built into git-filter-branch(1).

Comment: +1 thanks, the script is nice for me to learn about ruby's advantages :)

Comment: Will the script also transfer the messages that annotated the old tags?

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to do what you want using git.  'git rebase --tags' might be interesting but it does not exist.

If the commit messages are identical as you say then you could go through each tag in refs/tags, do:

```
'git log -1 --pretty=oneline <tagname>'
```

Compare the commit message to the full list:

```
'git log --pretty=oneline <newbranches>'
```

If you find a match (and the SHA1 hash is different) then do:

```
'git tag --force <tagname> <new SHA1>'
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to make `git filter-branch` automatically update modified tags using the `--tag-name-filter` option, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7673115/460005).

Answer (score 2):

According to Thomas Rast at http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Rebase-with-tags-td5582971.html:

> Leonid Podolny wrote:
>
> > Is it possible, at least, to receive a set of (old commit, new commit) 
> >     pairs, so that I will write a little script that will do that for me?
>
> **The post-rewrite hook gets this list, so you can use that if you want 
>   to.**

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a shot next time I try such a rebase. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have put together my own python implementation, `git rebasetags`

In case the rebase is interactive, you will be presented with a bash shell where you can make the changes. Upon exiting that shell, the tags will be restored.

[image]

From [this post](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/08/14/rebasing-in-git-without-losing-tags/)