# Why has git-filter-branch not rewritten tags?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I needed to split my git repo into two parts. I used the steps shown here: [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/359759#359759)

The command I used was:

```
 git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ABC HEAD -- --all
```

which seemed to work fine and left me with ABC as the root.

However now if if I try to checkout a tag that existed before I split the repo:

```
 git checkout an-old-tagname
```

it's recreating the old directory structure - so recreating ABC as a subdirectory, along with XYZ1 and XYZ2.

I know that is how the repo really looked at that point in time - but I want the tag to refer to just the ABC bits, as if they'd been at the root back then. I thought that's what filter-branch was doing when it re-wrote history, but obviously I don't grok it properly.

How can I get the tags re-written so I can go back in time while still having ABC be the root of the repo?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to specify

```
--tag-name-filter cat
```

to rewrite tags as well

Now, you could do

> #### `git filter-branch  --tag-name-filter cat` <sub><sup>...other filter options...</sup></sub> `-- --tags`

where <sub><sup>...other filter options...</sup></sub> repeats the filters you previously applied.

Comment: I can't rerun --subdirectory-filter again as the original subdir is now the root. Is there a way to get to the point where it is as if I'd run `--subdirectory-filter ... --tag-name-filter cat -- --tags` in the first place?

Comment: Nope, I'd expect you can run it 'again', as long as you run it against the tags. Remember, the tags were _NOT_ rewritten? You mention that yourself in the original post

Comment: @MalcolmBox I tweaked your tweak. Is it better like this?