# How do I permanently remove files in git from tags?

Tags: git

`git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch mysql_db' HEAD`

That's what I'm doing to remove `mysql_db` and that's fine. But now I have to do it from all my tags. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why has git-filter-branch not rewritten tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672907/why-has-git-filter-branch-not-rewritten-tags)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to rewrite tag-names as well (they will then point to the rewritten commits):

```
git filter-branch -f \
  --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch mysql_db' \
  --tag-name-filter 'cat' -- --all
```

Use `--all` to rewrite all commits, not just those reachable from the current `HEAD` commit.

From the [manpage of git filter-branch](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-filter-branch.html):

> *`--tag-name-filter`*
>
> […]
>
> The original tags are not deleted, but can be overwritten; use "--tag-name-filter cat" to simply update the tags. In this case, be very careful and make sure you have the old tags backed up in case the conversion has run afoul.

Comment: I think the OP wants to use something other than HEAD. Replacing HEAD in your command with "-- --all" should do the trick.

Comment: That depends if he wants to rewrite all commits reachable from HEAD or all commits, but yes, I agree. I'll update my question, just in case.