# trying to remove large file in git -- can't remove rev-list reference

Tags: git

I'm trying to entirely remove some very large files from my git repo history.  I've tried almost every solution I've ever seen offered, but I can never make the large file objects "unreachable" so that they will be garbage collected.  Here's a rundown of what I've tried:

```
    # finding the largest file
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -1
3d975c0908cde6010cbfcd0424eaf74c9dcf9f13 blob   1314240900 19175430 50462430

    # which file?
$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep  3d975c09
3d975c0908cde6010cbfcd0424eaf74c9dcf9f13 rawdata/brownfields/GEODATA_Featureclass_MAR2013.dbf

$ git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'git rm -fr --cached --ignore-unmatch rawdata'
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --verbose --all
$ git gc --aggressive --prune=now
$ git prune --expire now

$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep  3d975c09
3d975c0908cde6010cbfcd0424eaf74c9dcf9f13 rawdata/brownfields/GEODATA_Featureclass_MAR2013.dbf
```

I'm fairly confident that this file has been wiped clean from the history *except* for this pesky reference in the rev-list, which is what's not allowing it to be garbage-collected.

Is it true that this object will never be deleted if it shows up in the rev-list?  If so, how can I remove its reference from the rev-list?  I've tried so many commands, in so many different permutations, to no avail.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: With `rev-list` you are looking at all branches but you have run `filter-branch` only on the current branch. Have you determined which other branches this file is on?

Comment: What about remote branches and tags? `git branch -r` and `git rag` ?

Comment: Ah ha!  It was a tag.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672907/why-has-git-filter-branch-not-rewritten-tags) solved it

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had an old tag still referencing the large files, and wasn't aware that `filter-branch` does not operate on tags.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672907/why-has-git-filter-branch-not-rewritten-tags) led me in the right direction.

In short, I needed to add the `--tag-name-filter [tag]` option to `filter-branch`