# Git: Insert commit before one of the previous tags

Tags: android, git, github

I have an Android project repo in my GitHub which I use to tell some topics in my blog. After each topic, I create a tag. Here is my repo: https://github.com/figengungor/Suits

In my first tag, I created a RecyclerView and someone asked me to show how to add item click with RecyclerView which I didn't implement.

So my question is in this scenerio, how can I insert a commit before my first tag.

I want commit message to show up in this tag only but the commit effect should take place up to second last tag.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you the only one working on the project? Are you aware of the consequences of rewriting history?

Comment: So far, yes I'm the only one working on the project. And no, I'm not aware of the consequences. Can you enlighten me? The reason I want to do this is I added DataBinding in my last tag and I don't want to show adding item click listener with DataBinding. I want to add this click feature in my first tag and It will not conflict with anthing up to DataBinding tag.

Comment: And if you think that it'll cause me trouble, what do you suggest that I should do in this scenerio?

Comment: If you are the only committer, rewriting history is usually not an issue :)

Comment: In that case, how can I rewrite the history?

Answer (score 0):

- You can rewrite history by interactive rebase on top of particular commit
- With that you'll get whole new history regarding commits as objects (new sha1 hashes)
- Problem is that tags are essentialy objects with pointers to commits with some addtional informations
- 1. Get hash of last commit you want to keep intact and the one you want to insert

```
git rebase -i lastIntacthash
```

- 2. That will start your default editor
- 3. Crop whole line of your want-to-insert commit (pick ...)
- 4. Paste it as first line (eg. that would be first after intact commit)
- 5. Save file and git will do the rest
- In case you don't have many tags you can add them manually and delete old ones or refer to [Can tags be automatically moved after a git filter-branch and rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150685/can-tags-be-automatically-moved-after-a-git-filter-branch-and-rebase)