# Turn two commits with removing and adding files into one commit with file move

Tags: git, rebase

I imported SVN repository with Subgit and have problems with `git blame`.
The oldest revision for every source file is from 2014 year, even though the project was started in 2008.

This is caused by switching from Ant to Maven (it's Java project) which changed source directory structure from `/src/package/` to `/src/main/java/package`. With `svn log` i can see that there are two revosions for such purpose:

- in first one, the all source code was removed
- in the second one, the source files were added to follow Maven directory structure

That's why `git blame` can only show earliest revision from the day of Ant-> Maven migration.

Can i somehow rewrite git history to make git understand that all files were actually moved, but not removed and re-added?

Comment: Tracking a file in Git after it has moved is problematical, but in any case I don't see rebasing helping at all here, unless you rewrite history so that the file were never moved (probably not what you want to do).

Answer (score 3):

Use `git filter-branch` to remove the commit that removes all source files:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" = insert_SHA1_to_remove_here ];
    then
            skip_commit "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' --tag-name-filter cat --all
```

See [manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) for more details (search for "Darl").

Comment: Usually filter-branch should be done only as a last resort. But this method will work, and works even if your Git is so old it lacks `git replace`.

Comment: I think this could leave any branches created after that merge commit still attached to the old commit tree. They would need to be rebased onto the new commit as well. I'm not sure what happens to tags on these branches.

Comment: @Mort: the `--tag-name-filter` (which I just noticed is misspelled above) and `--all` take care of that.

Comment: @torek I've fixed `--tag-name-filter`. Thanks for pointing out the glitch.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like i will use this approach. I also has some git notes i want to preserve after history rewrite. How can i get old -> new hash mapping report after `git filter-branch` done it's job?

Comment: There is no direct way. But there is a backup of the old refs in `refs/original`.

Comment: @Derp: unfortunately the backup doesn't have a complete mapping.  If you know the skipped commits, or if you use a `--commit-filter` like this, you can compute or save the mapping. Filter-branch really should copy or move the notes for you (there's `git notes copy` to do the former, nothing to do the latter), but it doesn't. That's another reason not to run the filter-branch step, but rather just leave a `git replace` in place.

Answer (score 2):

#### You have three options

As far as Git is concerned, there is no such thing as a commit with a file move.  A commit is just a snapshot: "This is what's in."  That's it: no more, no less.  In other VCSes, a new commit B that follows an old commit A is *not* just a snapshot of "what's in", it's also "what changed", possibly including things like "renamed path/to/file to different/path/to/newname".  Git, however, chooses instead to (attempt to) *reconstruct* what changed, by—later, at the time you are looking at it—comparing the new contents of commit B to the old contents of commit A.

In general, Git steps back one commit at a time: compare Y-and-Z, then compare X-and-Y, then compare W-and-X, and so on.  That's what `git log` and `git blame` do, for instance.  Note that I've given the commits single letter names here, and assumed a linear sequence: `A--B--C--...--Z`.  In practice we need longer IDs, and not all sequences are linear (but with any luck the sequences right near this problem *are* linear).

What this means for you is that you must convince Git not to compare commit H ("commit that, vs G, has files under new name") to commit G ("commit that when compared to F, deletes files under old name") but rather to compare commit H to commit F, skipping over G.  In fact, perhaps we want to skip commit H as well, by comparing commit I (the one after H) to commit F (the one before G).  That's less critical than skipping over the commit that has the files deleted.

For all our options we need to know (or find) several of Git's commit IDs.  The four "particularly interesting" commits are:

- The commit where "all files are added again": it's H above, but let's call it `addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda` (which is actually a potentially-valid Git hash ID).   You will need to find the real ID.
- The commit where "all files are deleted".  This is the parent of the above, so we can name it using the funny suffix-hat (`^`) syntax that Git provides, by writing `addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda^`.  But let's just say we have the raw number as `de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e`.<sup>1</sup>
- We *may* also need to know the commit that comes *after* `addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda`.  This is the one we called "I" above: as Git is traversing history in reverse, commit `goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood`<sup>2</sup> leads Git to *reach* commit `addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda`, which leads Git to reach `de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e`, which of course leads Git to reach ...
- The commit before all the deletes.  Again, we can use the hat syntax for this—in fact, knowing the "good" commit ID, we can just use `goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood^`, then `goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood^^`, then `goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood^^^`, and so on.   But I'll just use `de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e^` for this one.

#### Option 1: just tell `git blame` to skip the commit

You have several ways to do this, but [for `git blame` in particular](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html), you have one option that is not directly available in other Git commands:

> -S <revs-file>
>          Use revisions from revs-file instead of calling [git-rev-list(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).

The documentation for this option is poor (in my opinion): the `-S` file argument is not a *revision list*, but rather a *graft list*.

What this means is that instead of `git blame <path>`, you can run:

```
echo addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda \
  $(git rev-parse de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e^) > \
  /tmp/graft
git blame -S /tmp/graft file-you-are-concerned-with
```

(or similar, depending on your OS).  See below for additional tricks, since you might want to skip the "add" commit too.  Of course the two raw commit IDs here need to be the right ones.

(If you have the raw ID of the commit before the "delete" commit, you can use that instead of invoking `git rev-parse`.  The nice thing about invoking `rev-parse` is that you can use abbreviated commits and thus get the full ones, plus of course all the usual gitrevisions syntax. The "echo" is to make sure both IDs are on the same line, as the `-S` file is handled the same way as the old Git grafts hack.)

#### Option 2: hide the commit more generally

If you want to hide the commit from *most* Git commands, you can do that more permanently *in one repository* (in a way that does not propagate elsewhere) using [`git replace`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html):

```
git replace --graft \
    addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda \
    de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e^
```

What we we are doing here is telling Git that whenever it's *about to* look at commit `addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda` it should turn its eyes<sup>3</sup> instead over to a *new* "replacement" commit.  The `git replace` command makes the new replacement commit by mostly copying `addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda`, but changing its parent from `de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e` to `de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e^`, i.e., the commit that came just before the "delete things" commit.

#### Option 3: really delete the commit(s)

It *is* possible to discard one or even both intermediate commits.  Let's say, for instance, we've decided to discard both `addaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddaddadda` and its previous `de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e`.  The drawback is that this effectively "re-numbers" every commit after that point: every commit starting from `goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood` forward.  The new, rewritten repository is no longer compatible with the old repository (and if you did your SVN-to-Git conversion with "notes" attached to each commit to remember the corresponding SVN revision, this process wrecks the notes).

To discard the two commits, start with the same the `git replace` thing as before.  This time, however, we want to replace `goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood` itself, with a copy that is just like `goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood`, except that its parent is the parent of `de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e`.  Hence:

```
git replace --graft goodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgoodgood \
    de1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e7ede1e^
```

Using our simple single-letter drawing again, what we've done is this:

```
             -------I'  <-- replacement for I
            /
A--...--E--F--G--H--I--J--...--Z   <-- HEAD
```

The graft makes Git jump from `I` to `I'` by "moving its eyes", so that it never sees `H` (the re-adds) nor `G` (the deletes) and jumps directly back to `F`.

Now that we have the graft in place, we can run `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --all`.  This obeys the graft while copying every commit it sees to new commits.<sup>4</sup>  The copies "before" the replacement `I'` are bit-for-bit identical to their originals, so they retain their original hash IDs.  The copy of `I'` remains `I'`, but the copies *after* `I'` are different, so they get new IDs.

Once the filtering is done, the `filter-branch` command replaces the old branch and tag names with new branch and tag names pointing to the new copies.  (The new tag names are the same as the old tag names, because our tag name filter was `cat`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It's the Cyberman commit!  You will be upgraded, or deleted!

<sup>2</sup>This is not a valid commit ID but there is a limit to what we can spell with `[0-9a-f]`. :-)

<sup>3</sup>Does Git even *have* eyes, or am I anthropomorphizing computers again?<sup>5</sup>

<sup>4</sup>While the identifying of commits is always done "backwards", from newest commits back to oldest, the copying that `git filter-branch` is (necessarily) done "forwards".  The way filter-branch works is to copy *every* commit, with the new copy made after applying any filters.  This is why it is so slow.  In our case we're doing the copy simply for its side effect of making replacements become permanent.

<sup>5</sup>"Don't anthropomorphize computers, they hate that." —author unknown

Answer (score 1):

Do you have lots of branches/tags created after the pair of commits in question? If you do, @j6t's `filter-branch` solution is probably the way to go.

Otherwise you could just `git reset --hard` to the second commit that added all of the files back. At that point, squash the two previous commits using `git rebase -i`, or `git reset HEAD~` followed by a `git commit`.
    At this point, you've squashed your two commits and you can use a `git rebase` to rebase all of the subsequent commits on the branch back onto the new squashed commit.

Comment: Yes, i have branches. And in this case rebase is not an option at all? I am ok with rewriting history in child branches

Comment: You could probably do that too. If you have tags, also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150685/can-tags-be-automatically-moved-after-a-git-filter-branch-and-rebase)