# Insert a commit into Git history without losing refs (tags, branches etc)

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a master branch for which I want to keep all history, including branches that have forked and merged back into the master branch, and tags:

```
                 (v1.2.3)
                     T
      A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H      (master)
          \      /
           I----J                 (topic/1)
```

Now, I want to insert an unrelated commit, X, into a specific position in the master branch (e.g. after commit A), like this:

```
                    (v1.2.3)
                        T
      A--X--B'-C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'  (master)
             \      /
              I'--J'              (topic/1)
```

I think that I want to do something that would be a combination of filter-branch and cherry-pick, similar to the last suggested method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898842/5778708).

How do I do this?

**Note:** I know that commit X will not introduce any conflicts. Also, I want to scale this solution to more than one commit (I currently have a script that, given a SHA on master, knows which commit(s), if any, need to be inserted after the master commit).

Comment: Why are you adding a commit so early in history? Rebasing like that habitually will mess up anyone else who has that repo checked out. There's probably a better way to solve whatever problem you have.

Comment: So, what I am trying to do is actually to merge several repos into one. The structure is that there is one main repo with a lot of commits, branches and tags where I need to preserve all history, and then some smaller support repos that I want to merge into the main repo, with their commits appearing in the correct order in the master repo (but tags and branches from the smaller repos are not important - all I need are the commits from master in chronological order). Also, this will be a new repo, so everyone will switch from the old repo to the new repo at some point.

Comment: By "correct order" I assume you mean by date. You're going to interleave the history from multiple repos to pretend like they were one all along. This will create an artificial history that bears no relation to how the pieces were developed and will hinder code archeology (ie. figuring out why code was written). I would suggest you instead ask a question about your repo merge and how to best handle it.

Comment: I am aware of that. The point is that the main repo is the only repo that needs to be complete. The commits from the support repos are only there to be able to be able to check out a tag, for instance, and know (within a commit or two) that the code in the support repos will be compatible with the main repo (e.g. API compatibility).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can tags be automatically moved after a git filter-branch and rebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150685/can-tags-be-automatically-moved-after-a-git-filter-branch-and-rebase)

Comment: @m-bitsnbites There are much easier ways to merge repos. Try asking the question.

Comment: I am currently trying out [git-stitch-repo](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Git-FastExport/script/git-stitch-repo) (after some CPAN struggling), but it does not seem to be working properly for our repositories. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Schwern, I asked a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976798/how-to-merge-several-git-repos-into-one-and-interleave-histories]), to see if I have any better luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking out A, doing commit X, then rebasing master onto X while preserving merges.

- `git checkout A`
- ...edit, add, and commit X...
- `git checkout master`
- `git rebase -p X`

Unfortunately this does not preserve tags.  There are ways to solve that, but from your comment on the post there's better ways to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: Could you please reference such a better way? For instance, I have tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/618113/5778708, but it just merges the different repos in a big merge commit on the tip of master, so I can't easily check out a branch or commit from the past and expect it to include all the files from all the repositories.

Comment: @m-bitsnbites You can use `git tag --merged <branch>` to find all tags which will probably be affected by the rebase. Figuring out what commit to remap them on, that I don't know. Like I said, there are better ways to solve your problem.