# How to merge several Git repos into one and interleave histories

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

My situation is that I have two Git repositories that I need to merge into a single repository (there are actually more repos, but I can start with two).

The two repositories are:

- The main repository, **A**.
- The second repository, **B**.

The code in repository **B** has dependencies on the code in repository **A** (but *not* vice versa), and the histories of both repositories follow each other in a chronological fashion - roughly (i.e. a specific commit in repo **B** will typically require a commit from repo **A** with a very similar commit time).

There are conflicting branch and tag names in both repositories (there are no guarantees that they belong together), but only the refs from **A** need to be preserved.

The requirements for the new repository, **C**, are:

1. All refs (branches and tags) from **A** need to be preserved.
2. Only the master branch commits from **B** need to be preserved (i.e. the commits that are reported by `git log --first-parent master`).
3. The files from each source repository should be put into subfolders of the new repository (i.e. the files from **A** shall go into `A/`, and the files form **B** shall go into `B/`).
4. When checking out a specific commit (including commits done *before* the merge) in repository **C** (e.g. a release tag) compatible files form both source repositories should be found in the directories `A/` and `B/` (at least within a commit or two).

So far I have tried several approaches, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories/618113#618113) and [git-stitch-repo](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Git-FastExport/script/git-stitch-repo), without success (they did not fulfill the above requirements).

At this point, I have managed to:

- Move all files in each repo to a subdirectory using git filter-branch. E.g. for repo **A**:

```
mkdir A
mv * .gitignore A/ 2> /dev/null
git commit -a -m 'DROPME' > /dev/null
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&A/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE" ||:' -- --all
git reset --hard origin/master
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

- Import repo **B** into **A** using [git fast-export](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-export)/[fast-import](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import).
- Device a method for generating a mapping such that for a given SHA in **A**, there is a list of zero, one or more SHA:s that should be inserted from **B**.

What I would expect now, is that some clever usage of [git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) should enable me to insert the selected commits from **B** into the master branch of **A**. But how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution turned out to be much more involved than I had hoped for. It involves manipulating and combining the output of two (or more) `git fast-export` streams, and importing them into a new repository using `git fast-import`.

In short, a new `fast-import` stream is generated by traversing two input streams, and switching back-and-forth between them based on a date-sorted log from the main branches.

I have implemented the solution in a Python script called `join-git-repos.py`, that I put in a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/mbitsnbites/git-tools).

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for open-sourcing the script!! +1

Answer (score 0):

First, move everything in repo A to the subdirectory A/. Nothing fancy, just `git mv`. This preserves all branches and tags and commit IDs in A.

Then use `git subtree` to make the master branch of B a subtree of A in directory B/.

```
git subtree add -P B/ <remote for B> master
```

And you're done.

---

If you want old release tags on A to also reflect what would have been in B at that time... oy. You can do this without messing up your history too badly by merging B into A just before each release tag.

You have this.

```
          * - * - *           * - * - * branch
    v1   /         \    v2   /
* - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * - * master
                                   /
  * -- * ---- * - * - * --------- *
```

The bottom line of commits is B. B's commits are laid out so they line up in time with A's.

And you want something like this.

```
          * - * - *           * - * - * branch
    v1   /         \    v2   /
* * * - * - * - * - * * * - * - * - * master
  |                   |            /
  * -- * ---- * - * - * --------- *
```

This has merged B into A just before each release tag. This avoids making up an artificial history of A and B being developed together.

I don't know how to do that in an automated fashion. The problem is `rebase` does not preserve tags, only merges. So adding the merge commit to v1 will lose the v2 tag and I'm not sure how to identify what the original commit of a rebased commit is.

Good luck.

Comment: I will try it, but I don't see how this solution could satisfy requirement 4 in the question. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @m-bitsnbites You want old release tags from repo A to take a guess at what was in repo B at the time? That's going to mess up your history real bad. I don't know if it's even logically possible while also preserving the branch history of A.

Comment: @m-bitsnbites I put together an illustration of the resulting repository structure that's IMO the best compromise, but I don't know how to do the transform in an automated fashion.

Comment: Does this chronologically interleave histories? When I tried using `subtree` and checked the history with `git log`, the commits were out of chronological order and B's commits sat on top of later commits in A.