# Interleaving two Git repositories

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, git-filter-repo

How can I join two Git repositories by interleaving their commit history according to commit / author date?

We can assume both repositories contain separate files. However, folder names might be identical and should be deep merged.

For example, repository `a` looks like:

```
a1.txt
src/a2.txt
```

```
A1---A2---A3    <--- a/main
```

While repository `b` looks like:

```
b1.txt
src/b2.txt
```

```
B1---B2---B3    <--- b/main
```

Assuming the commit / author date order is `A1`, `B1`, `B2`, `A2`, `A3`, `B3`, the resulting repository `c` should look like:

```
a1.txt
b1.txt
src/a2.txt
src/b2.txt
```

```
A1---B1---B2---A2---A3---B3    <--- c/main
```

We can also assume that no two commit / author dates will be identical such that the order is well defined.

---

This is unlike [Merge two Git repositories without breaking file history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history/62096626#62096626) which keeps two branches and creates a merge commit.

This may be a simpler case of [How to merge several Git repos into one and interleave histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976798/how-to-merge-several-git-repos-into-one-and-interleave-histories)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the 2 histories relate to different things, you might be able to pull it off if you are able to list all revisions by their commit (or author) date..... I do *not* think that if you ask `git log` to show you revisions from both branches, it will intertwine them.... so you might have to sort them first before.... so, setup a repository so that you have access to both branches. Create a new empty branch (`git checkout --orphan` and clean the content), then this should work:

```
git log --pretty="%at %h" branch1 branch2 | sort -n | while read date revision; do git cherry-pick $revision; done
```

Or something along those lines

Taking @LeGEC's comment in, then it could be adjusted to this:

```
git log --reverse --date-order --pretty="%h" branch1 branch2 | while read revision; do git cherry-pick $revision; done
```

Comment: sorting by author date outside of git (`.. | sort -n | ...`) can move commits around and break the parent - child order. I would suggest `git log --date-order ...`, which *preserves parent - child order*, and reorders by date when it can.

Comment: Good catch! Perhaps by commit date?

Comment: just use `--date-order` : `git log --date-order branch1 branch2` will preserve parent-child order, and will interleave `branch1` and `branch2` history (since these two histories aren't related, git can choose how to order the commits one with respect to another)