# How to rewrite commit history?

Tags: git, git-branch

After creating branch `Y` from working branch `X`, I deleted some files to reduce visual noise by not seeing those files around on the FS, while working on branch `Y`. These files are being changed in branch `X`.

here is the scenario:

```
A - B [origin/master]
     \
      C - D - G - H [origin/X]
           \
            E - F [Y]
```

---

Changes from branch `Y` are also pushed to `origin/Y`

Already raised a PR request on branch `Y` for review.

---

How to rewrite the commit history in `origin/Y` to get a file back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undelete a file previously deleted in git's history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150394/how-to-undelete-a-file-previously-deleted-in-gits-history)

Comment: @eftshift0 Branch `Y` is already on PR request on latest commit. Is this query not  different from attached?

Comment: that part is not explained there... but the recipe to get the files back is still the same.... now, when you get your corrected branch, then you do: `git push -f origin Y`. After you have force-pushed the branch, the PR should update on github or bitbucket.

Comment: @eftshift0 I have the `parent of the commit that deleted the file` say `id1`. What is `id of the previous commit` in step 2 below? I have more than one file deleted  after `id1`

Comment: The parent ID is the id you use to run the `git checkout <rev-id> -- <deleted-filepath>` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a simple recipe as a fallback, just in case. Suppose your branch is called A, and you deleted files on A~3 (that would be, 3 revisions behind A):

```
git checkout A~3 # we set ourselves on the revision where the files where deleted
git checkout HEAD~1 -- file1 file2 file3 # get back the files from the previous revision
git commit --amend --no-edit # commit new revision with the deleted files back in place
git cherry-pick A~3..A # replay revisions after this new revision
# if you like the results:
git branch -f A # set the branch on this new position
git checkout A
git push -f origin A
```

That should work

Comment: I see [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150424/3317808) more simple... Because in my case one file is deleted an one file is renamed and modified. But this is changing my commit history.

Comment: Commit history is gonna change... at least the content of the revisions... even if you keep the same line of revisions with comment/author, you are rewriting history.

Comment: So, I want to apply [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150424/3317808) on the commit am currently on. But isn't this going to require a new commit after applying this aproach and then push those changes? Because I have a PR request that is on current commit?

Comment: So, what you want is to create a new additional revision where you get the files back? Sure, it's possible.... not the most elegant way to handle it, but possible.... and sure, you will need a new commit after the checkout of the deleted files.

Comment: After commit history changes, does `git push -u origin Y` create any issue? because commit history is changed in local branch `Y`?

Comment: If you didn't rewrite history and only added a revision to get the files back? There should be no problem.

Comment: I will just add a new commit(revision) to get the files back. But before that, how do I deal with PR request that is on current commit? Does that PR request stop me creating new commit(revision) and push?

Comment: github and bitbucket (if you are using them) will reflect the update of the PR when you push into the branch that was used to create the PR.

Comment: Being on current commit, after following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150394/how-to-undelete-a-file-previously-deleted-in-gits-history/3150424#3150424), commit history is changing. `git push ` may not work ... How to make `origin/Y` in sync with local `Y`?

Comment: what do you mean? If you didn't rewrite the history of Y and you only added a revision, push will not fail. It will fail if you rewrote history.

Comment: My bad... commit history did not change. `git push` went fine

Comment: Now... can I rebase with parent branch? Because I have files back after creating a new revision with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150424/3317808)?

Answer (score 1):

As @eftshift0 mentioned in the comments, you might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150528/10576762) useful.
It shows that you can restore the lost file and rewrite the git history with the following:

```
git rebase -i <id of the commit with the files before they were deleted>
git checkout <id of the commit previous to the one you're currently on> <filename>
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
git tag -d originalHead
```

Nevertheless, there is value in keeping the git history unaltered, so another option to recover the lost file without changing git history can be found at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150424/10576762), which says this:

`git checkout <id of the commit with the files before they were deleted> <filename>`

In addition, if you want to recover multiple files this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555154/10576762) shows some ways to do that, which could for example be running the `git checkout` command multiple times.

Comment: `previous commit` would be the commit that was previous to the commit where the files disappeared. In addition, if you want to recover multiple files this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555154/10576762) shows some ways to do that. I will update my answer.

Comment: From the directory am running these commands, there are two files deleted in subdirectory `dir1`.

Comment: Does this also maintain the new files created in latest commit?

Comment: It should. Take a look at `git status`.

Comment: `git checkout` will maintain the new files in the latest commit unless you checkout a file that you've modified in your current branch.

Comment: In your answer, Is `id of the commit with the files before they were deleted` in step 1 same as `id of the commit previous to the one without the files` in step 2?

Comment: Not necessarily, my bad on the confusing wording. `id of the commit with the files before they were deleted` is the id of the parent commit that deleted the files, but `id of the commit previous to the one without the files` is just the commit before the one you're currently working on. I've updated the post to make step 2 a little more clear.

Comment: What is the idea about checkout to `id of commit previous to the one am currently on` in step 2? why not the commit that am currently on ?

Comment: probably `HEAD` will work just as well on checkout... but I didn't want to add some pepper to a recipe that has been already tried and tested (from what you can see on all the upvotes).

Comment: @eftshift0  Am following second approach, but I see commit history changing