# Setting git parent pointer to a different parent

Tags: git

If I have a commit in the past that points to one parent, but I want to change the parent that it points to, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 492, accepted):

Using [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). It's the generic "take commit(s) and plop it/them on a different parent (base)" command in Git.

Some things to know, however:

1. Since commit SHAs involve their parents, when you change the parent of a given commit, its SHA will change - as will the SHAs of *all* commits which come after it (more recent than it) in the line of development.
2. If you're working with other people, and you've already pushed the commit in question public to where they've pulled it, modifying the commit is probably a Bad Idea™. This is due to #1, and thus the resulting confusion the other users' repositories will encounter when trying to figure out what happened due to your SHAs no longer matching theirs for the "same" commits. *(See the "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" section of the linked man page for details.)*

That said, if you're currently on a branch with some commits that you want to move to a new parent, it'd look something like this:

```
git rebase --onto <new-parent> <old-parent>
```

That will move everything *after* `<old-parent>` in the current branch to sit on top of `<new-parent>` instead.

Comment: I'm using git rebase --onto to change parents but it seems that I end up with only a single commit. I put up a question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181665/git-rebase-onto-results-on-single-commit

Comment: Aha, so THAT is what `--onto` is used for! The documentation has always been completely obscure to me, *even* after reading this answer!

Comment: This line: `git rebase --onto <new-parent> <old-parent>` Told me everything about how to use `rebase --onto` that every other question and document I've read so far failed to.

Comment: For me this command should read: `rebase this commit on that one`, or `git rebase --on <new-parent> <commit>`. Using the old parent here doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @kopranb The old parent is important when you want to discard some of the path from your head to the remote head. The case you are describing is handled by `git rebase <new-parent>`.

Comment: To put it another way, `--onto` and your old parent are important if you are rebasing because your upstream rebased, or you are changing upstreams, rather than just following the upstream forward.

Comment: while doing so _**git rebase --onto remotes/origin/feature/new_parent remotes/origin/**_ I'm getting this **invalid upstream remotes/origin/**. So I tried _**git rebase --onto remotes/origin/feature/new_parent/my_branch remotes/origin/my_branch**_ but then it giving _**Does not point to a valid commit: remotes/origin/feature/new_parent/my_branch**_ Any suggestion what is wrong here ? @Amber

Comment: make sure you add `origin` in front, something like this:
`git rebase --onto origin/<new_branch> origin/<old_branch>`

Comment: In my case, I had pushed to remote branch and even raised an MR. Doing this and pushing it was rejected because parent branch was more updated. I simply had to delete the remote branch with `git push --delete origin branchname` and then pushed again

Answer (score 36):

If it turns out that you need to avoid rebasing the subsequent commits (e.g. because a history rewrite would be untenable), then you can use the [*git replace*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html) (available in Git 1.6.5 and later).

```
# …---o---A---o---o---…
#
# …---o---B---b---b---…
#
# We want to transplant B to be "on top of" A.
# The tree of descendants from B (and A) can be arbitrarily complex.

replace_first_parent() {
    old_parent=$(git rev-parse --verify "${1}^1") || return 1
    new_parent=$(git rev-parse --verify "${2}^0") || return 2
    new_commit=$(
      git cat-file commit "$1" |
      sed -e '1,/^$/s/^parent '"$old_parent"'$/parent '"$new_parent"'/' |
      git hash-object -t commit -w --stdin
    ) || return 3
    git replace "$1" "$new_commit"
}
replace_first_parent B A

# …---o---A---o---o---…
#          \
#           C---b---b---…
#
# C is the replacement for B.
```

With the above replacement established, any requests for the object B will actually return the object C. The contents of C are exactly the same as the contents of B except for the first parent (same parents (except for the first), same tree, same commit message).

Replacements are active by default, but can be turned of by using the `--no-replace-objects` option to *git* (before the command name) or by setting the `GIT_NO_REPLACE_OBJECTS` environment variable. Replacements can be shared by pushing `refs/replace/*` (in addition to the normal `refs/heads/*`) .

If you do not like the commit-munging (done with *sed* above), then you could create your replacement commit using higher level commands:

```
git checkout B~0
git reset --soft A
git commit -C B
git replace B HEAD
git checkout -
```

The big difference is that this sequence does not propagate the additional parents if B is a merge commit.

Comment: And then, how would you push the changes to an existing repository ? It seems to work locally, but git push does not push anything after that

Comment: @BaptisteWicht: The replacements are stored in a separate set of refs. You will need to arrange to push (and fetch) the `refs/replace/` ref hierarchy. If you just need to do it once, then you can do `git push yourremote 'refs/replace/*'` in the source repository, and `git fetch yourremote 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'` in the destination repositories. If you need to do it multiple times, then you could instead add those refspecs to a `remote.yourremote.push` config variable (in the source repository) and a `remote.yourremote.fetch` config variable (in the destination repositories).

Comment: A simpler way to do this is to use ``git replace --grafts``. Not sure when this was added, but its whole purpose is to create a replacement that is the same as commit _B_ but with the specified parents.

Answer (score 34):

<sup>*Note that changing a commit in Git requires that all commits that follow it alse have to be changed.  This is discouraged if you have published this part of history, and somebody might have build their work on history that it was before change.*</sup>

Alternate solution to `git rebase` mentioned in [Amber's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810348/setting-git-parent-pointer-to-a-different-parent/3810400#3810400) is to use **grafts** mechanism (see definition of Git grafts in [Git Glossary](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) and documentation of `.git/info/grafts` file in [Git Repository Layout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html) documentation) to change parent of a commit, check that it did correct thing with some history viewer (`gitk`, `git log --graph`, etc.) and then use **[`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)** (as described in "Examples" section of its manpage) to make it permanent (and then remove graft, and optionally remove the original refs backed up by `git filter-branch`, or reclone repository):

```
echo "$commit-id $graft-id" >> .git/info/grafts
git filter-branch $graft-id..HEAD
```

**NOTE !!!** This solution is **different from rebase solution** in that `git rebase` would rebase / transplant ***changes***, while grafts-based solution would simply reparent commits ***as is***, not taking into account differences between old parent and new parent!

Comment: From what I understand (from https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint), `git replace` has superseded git grafts (assuming you have git 1.6.5 or later).

Comment: @Thr4wn: Largely true, but if you want to **rewrite history** then grafts + git-filter-branch (or interactive rebase, or fast-export + e.g. reposurgeon) is the way to do it.  If you want/need to **preserve history**, then git-replace is far superior to grafts.

Comment: @JakubNarębski, could you explain what you mean by *rewrite* vs *preserve* history? Why can't I use `git-replace` + `git-filter-branch`? In my test, `filter-branch` seemed to respect the replacement, rebasing the entire tree.

Comment: @cdunn2001: `git filter-branch` rewrites history, respecting grafts and replacements (but in rewritten history replacements will be moot); push will result in non fasf-forward change. `git replace` creates in-place transferable replacements; push will be fast-forward, but you would need to push `refs/replace` to transfer replacements to have corrected history. HTH

Answer (score 30):

*To clarify the above answers and shamelessly plug my own script:*

It depends on whether you want to "rebase" or "reparent".  A *rebase*, as suggested by [Amber](/a/3810400/303425), moves around *diffs*.  A *reparent*, as suggested by [Jakub](/a/3811028/303425) and [Chris](/a/3811217/303425), moves around *snapshots* of the whole tree.  If you want to reparent, I suggest using [`git reparent`](https://github.com/MarkLodato/git-reparent) rather than doing the work manually.

#### Comparison

Suppose you have the picture on the left and you want it to look like the picture on the right:

```
                   C'
                  /
A---B---C        A---B---C
```

Both rebasing and reparenting will produce the same picture, but the definition of `C'` differs.  With `git rebase --onto A B`, `C'` will not contain any changes introduced by `B`.  With `git reparent -p A`, `C'` will be identical to `C` (except that `B` will not be in the history).

Comment: +1 I have experimented with the `reparent` script; it works beautifully; **highly recommended**. I would also recommend creating a new `branch` label, and to `checkout` that branch before calling (as the branch label will move).

Comment: It's also worth noting that: (1) the original node remains intact, and (2) the new node does not inherit the original node's children.

Answer (score 7):

Definitely @Jakub's answer helped me some hours ago when I was trying the exact same thing as the OP.
However, `git replace --graft`  is now the easier solution regarding grafts. Also, a major problem with that solution was that filter-branch made me loose every branch that wasn't merged into the HEAD's branch. Then, `git filter-repo` did the job perfectly and flawlessly.

```sh
$ git replace --graft <commit> <new parent commit>
$ git filter-repo --force
```

I've made a question like this some time ago, so the complete answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62475366/12603421).

---

Fore more info: checkout the section "Re-grafting history" in the [docs](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#cheat-sheet-conversion-of-examples-from-the-filter-branch-manpage)

Comment: ```git filter-repo``` requires 2.22 or later