# Git: how to use rebase with theirs strategy

Tags: git, rebase

Basically, I just want to (re)set the parent (let's say to commit `A`) of a specific commit (commit `B`) which is the root commit of some branch `x`. It is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163895/git-setting-a-commits-parent-without-rebase) in one of the answers that I can do that via grafts. I will try that later, maybe it's the better way.

However, before reading this, I thought that this should be possible via `rebase`. But because the parent commit `A` differs a bit from `B` and I just want to stay the whole branch `x` the way it is, just with setting a parent to its root commit `B`, I thought I might use the `theirs` strategy -- which doesn't seem to exist. I have stumbled upon this earlier (and thought it was a bug or in my Git installation) and always just worked-around by switching branches and using the `ours` strategy. However, with `rebase`, I am forced to use the `theirs` strategy in this case.

My command looks like:

```
git rebase -s theirs --onto A --root x x--rebased
```

Comment: Not exactly what you need, but there are ways to simulate a "theirs strategy": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267

Comment: @VonC: I think you didn't know what I meant. I know how to simulate it. The problem is, this doesn't work together with `rebase`.

Comment: hence the "not exactly what you need part". This was to let others know about the "theirs" strategy in general.

Answer (score 2):

rebase isn't designed for what you want to do. The other poster was correct; what you want to do is set up a graft to attach B to A, then run `git filter-branch` to bake it into the commits. An example of this exact use case can be found in the [`git filter-branch` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

Comment: Just curios: If there would be the `theirs` strategy, how would that be in any way different? And if this would not be different, why would it be bad to use `rebase` here? But anyway, this question was not about how to achieve that but how to use the `theirs` strategy with `rebase`. How to achieve that, that was already answered in another separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088551/git-what-is-a-graftcommit-or-a-graft-id).

Comment: @Albert, rebase applies every commit on the branch as a patch. This linearizes history, and brings up the possibility of merge conflicts. If your history has no parent commit, this means you'll have a new file/new file conflict, and I suspect a take-theirs strategy might end up simply emptying out the first commit in the sequence entirely...

Comment: The sides are swapped at rebasing, i.e. the theirs strategy is actually the ours strategy. I.e. the first commit will exactly stay as it is. As well for all the other commits.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but if your aim is to go from this:

```
o C (X)
|
o B

o A
```

to this:

```
o C' (X)
|
o B'
|
o A
```

then `git replace --graft B A` should do what you want.

N.B. `B` and `B'` have the same filetrees as each other, but different commit hashes because their parent commits are different. Likewise `C` and `C'`.

*Why this has to be done via `git replace --graft` rather than `git rebase -s theirs`, I don't know. Presumably it is for [hysterical raisins](http://catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html).*

*Also see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18027030/82216) to [How do git grafts and replace differ? (Are grafts now deprecated?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800692/how-do-git-grafts-and-replace-differ-are-grafts-now-deprecated).*