# Svn2git isn't attaching branches to parents

Tags: git, svn, branch

Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but I'm running svn2git to convert an SVN repo to a git repo with branches and tags preserved. For some reason, the branches and tags are not descendents of master when the conversion is completed, which is pretty annoying.

The repository I want to convert is at http://ros.berkeley.edu/svn/berkeley-ros-pkg/stacks/berkeley_demos/. It should be in the standard layout as far as I can tell.

If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in `git svn`, e.g. `git svn clone --stdlayout` instead of svn2git? That usually works just fine.

Comment: Same result; I think there's actually something stupid about the way the trunks and branches were created for this repository so now I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite history to attach parents forcefully. Paging @VonC :)

Comment: Aha this guy had the same problem and found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163895/git-setting-a-commits-parent-without-rebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a possible solution (unfortunately this didn't come up when I searched for my original problem but when I searched on how to mangle history to change the parent of a commit I found it) [git - setting a commit's parent without rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163895/git-setting-a-commits-parent-without-rebase)

Edit: Yay! Grafts are the way to go, since I'm really only doing this temporarily to figure out what the svn branch history looks like (go figure - it's completely linear but it goes from trunk, to a tag (which really became a branch) to a branch). When i do the proper conversion rebase will work too.