# How to "move" a git merge?

Tags: git

I started with a similar problem as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163895/git-setting-a-commits-parent-without-rebase) and did some rebase and merge action and in one case ended up with the following.

```
---a---b---c---d---   master
    \         /
     x---y---z        thebranch
```

I must have done something wrong when merging (given wrong SHA?), because what I needed was the following

```
---a---b---c---d---   master
    \     /    
     x---y---z        thebranch
```

My question is now, how can I achieve this? Are grafts the way to go for or is there more straight-forward?

Comment: So, "c" was a normal commit which you want to be a merge of "y" instead?

Comment: @che Yes, correct. The repo was migrated from SVN to Git, which may explain the not so Git-like state of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to master branch.

   `git checkout master`
2. I presume `d` is a merge commit. So, we can discard it.

   `git reset --soft c` //it brings your master branch back to `c`.
3. Merge `y` now.

   `git merge y`

Answer (score 0):

```
$> git checkout master           # go to master
$> git reset --hard c            # roll back to c, discarding the merge-commit d
$> git merge y                   # merge y into c, creating a new merge-commit d'
```

by doign that

```
---a---b---c---d---   master
    \         /
     x---y---z        thebranch
```

effectively becomes

```
---a---b---c---d'---      master
    \         /    
     x-------y---z        thebranch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b by b
git merge y
```

This should get you

```
---a---b---by---    by
    \     /
     x---y---z      thebranch
```

---

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard c
```

This should get you

```
         c -- master
        /
---a---b---by---    by
    \     /
     x---y---z      thebranch
```

---

```
git rebase --onto by HEAD^
git branch -d by
```

This should get you:

```
---a---b---by---c'    master
    \     /
     x---y---z      thebranch
```

...i think :-)