# Restoring History within two loosely forked git projects

Tags: git, git-merge

There are 3 projects each with their own git repo:

- **Project A**, a project independent of B
- **Project B**, a project independent of A
- **Project AB**, a project that uses some of A and some of B. An amalgamation of sources, file structures, etc, with some modifications to allow the two to blend properly.

Project A and Project B are mostly dead, but did receive minor patches after AB was created, some of which were later ported to AB. AB's git repo was created without history from either A or B. It is easy for me to tell which file or directory came from A and which came from B, and I know what commit each of the initial files was taken from.

**How do I Restore history for AB before the init, assuming that all files in AB are based on files from A or B?**

Keep in mind the following:

- Files from A may be in a B-like directory, and vice versa, so I should be able to handle moves
- At some point, I'd like to rebase AB's ported patches so that they are attributed to a merge from either A or B.
- I would like for A or B to be able to merge AB, although having only one of them be able to do this would be okay, as long as I can control which one.
- There are about 30-50 files, so it would still be possible for me to rebase for each file, it would be preferred if I didn't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you’d probably want to set A and B as parents of your root commit. You can see here how to do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4164767/758345

Git will now understand where these files are coming from and also handle renames etc. You should now be able to merge from A and B into AB.

You can never merge AB into A or B, as AB also contains the other project. You might be able to use cherry-picking, but I doubt that too. If you want changes from AB to be contributed to A and B, you should have a look at submodules and git-subtree.

Comment: What I really meant by merging AB into A or B was to introduce A files to B or B files to A by making AB accessible to A maintainers or B maintainers. The goal is really to move on with AB, but to reach out to people "stuck" in A or B.

Comment: As I said, merging AB into A or B is *very* problematic, unless A and B are in separate directories within AB. Alternatively, you could write a helper script that sorts out the parts of AB that belong to A or B. But to my knowledge, git does not contain any functionality of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

To create commits before your `root-commit` would require a `rebase` of the entire `AB` repo.

Perhaps a different way to bring in those old commits would be 
[**orphan branches**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository)

```
git checkout --orphan project-a
git rm -rf .
git remote add upstream-a git://foo.org/project-a
git pull upstream-a master

git checkout --orphan project-b
git rm -rf .
git remote add upstream-b git://foo.org/project-b
git pull upstream-b master
```

Comment: I think I'd like to rebase because it maintains a directed history of the files. My goal is to have the repo AB in a state where patches can be sent to A or B or both A and B so that collaboration can occur between AB and the projects it forked from.