# Rebase a single commit to HEAD

Tags: git, rebasing

I would like to rebase a given commit to be HEAD of my current branch.  Of course I can use `git rebase -i <future-head-SHA>~` and then move it down to HEAD (as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507510/git-move-a-commit-on-top)), but I want to automate this process.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe consider looking into cherry-pick?

Comment: Well, the commit is already in my branch, what would cherry-pick do in this case?

Comment: Oh I see. It’s not elsewhere in the tree

Comment: Yes, I want to reorder the commits so that a specific commit is on top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: move a commit "on top"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507510/git-move-a-commit-on-top)

Comment: I don’t think there is an automated git command for this. Instead you might need to write a shell script.

Comment: yep, my question is if there is a way to to this without workaround/external scripts/whatnot

Comment: What is the purpose to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Interactive rebase is the only tool designed to do this kind of thing. You could, hypothetically, script this, though:

- Write a script that reads the list of `rebase -i` instructions from the file passed as its first argument - the file you'd normally get to edit yourself in an editor -, and writes a re-ordered list back into that file.
- Tell Git to use that script as an editor when starting the interactive rebase, so that it's used to rewrite the rebase instructions instead of letting you edit them manually.

The following should work, provided you have GNU sed installed (other editions of sed usually don't support the `-i` flag):

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e '1 {h; d}; $ {p; g}'" git rebase -i <commit>~
```

Comment: In general, you should use `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` rather than `GIT_EDITOR` so as to affect only the edit of the `pick` commands. Of course as long as none of the pick commands become `edit` or `squash` it won't matter as Git won't be running `$GIT_EDITOR` during that same process session.

Answer (score -1):

git rebase commit-id

This command do the job for you.