# Re-basing onto a specific commit

Tags: git

I checked [Git: How to rebase to a specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744049/git-how-to-rebase-to-a-specific-commit) but I couldn't understand, my problem is not similar

- I have a branch in which I have 2 commits `x` and `y`.
- I add another commit `z` in that branch and want to squash it with `x`.
- Every time I open a text editor to rebase, it shows commit `y` only and
  I am not able to rebase it with `x`.

Edit:

I tried using:

```
git rebase -i x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this one way by just making the `z` commit on top of the `x` and `y` commits:

```
# from your branch
git commit -m 'z commit'
```

Then, we can do an interactive rebase, reorder the commits, and squash.  Type the following:

```
git rebase -i --root your_branch
```

This should bring up an editor window, showing your three commits from *oldest* to *newest*:

```
pick dj39fm2 message for commit x
pick m83mdk2 message for commit y
pick 3kme92w message for commit z
```

Now, reorder the commits such that `z` comes right after `x`, and then change the option for commit `z` to `squash`, to tell Git that you want to squash it down to the `x` commit:

```
pick dj39fm2 message for commit x
squash 3kme92w message for commit z
pick m83mdk2 message for commit y
```

Now save the file, exit the editor, and allow Git to start the rebase.  Note that you might get some merge conflicts during the squash, or as the `y` commit reapplied to a new base.

Comment: Is there any way to move the order or I would just have to retype it?

Comment: @ThunderKnight I have given what I believe is the best answer.  Please try it, and if you get stuck somewhere, then let me know.