# Merge changed files from feature to a hotfix git flow

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-branch, git-flow

I have 3 branches

develop, master and a feature branch which is made with git flow feature start.

Now I want to make the commits which are made from the feature to be merged into a separate hotfix so I can merge it into the master without merging the developer branch into the master how can I do that?

To clerify

develop has 100+ commits which are made for a separate release,

I made branch out of the dev, and want to make it into a separate hotfix.

The problem is a hotix is a master originating branch, so if I do git merge feature git will merge ALL of the developer commits with the few commits I amde on the feature.

The question is. how to cherry pick the feature?

EDIT:

@Pigueiras

I am more like in this situation, I draw a diagram.
[image]

I need to ONLY transfer the red noted commits from the feature to the hotfix.

Comment: If you want to put more info in the question, edit the question with the stuff, don't put another answer :). Also the references to other people with @ doesn't work if they are not a comment :(, that's why I didn't know that you were asking me more things. Is it OK now with my answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you want to use a `rebase --onto`. In the git documentation you have an example about [how to move the parent of the branch that you are using](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#More-Interesting-Rebases).

In your case, you should do:

```
git rebase --onto hotfix develop feature/branch
```

Also related: [Setting git parent pointer to a different parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810348/setting-git-parent-pointer-to-a-different-parent).

Be aware that this is a rebase, so don't do that if the commits are published for more developers.

Answer (score 0):

You also also just create a hotfix of master.
Then from inside the hotfix branch:

```
git merge feature/branch
```

This should be a save and simple way to achive what you need.