# Rebasing to change parent of a merge commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

Suppose I've got the following history, where the top line is the master branch, the lower one is a feature branch that's merged with master at one point, and `D` just reverts `C` (which means that the working directory is the same in `B` and `D`).

```
A---B---C---D           master
 \   \
  E---F---G             feature
```

I want to add `C` and its reversion `D` to the history before the merge in `F`, like this:

```
A---B---C---D           master
 \           \
  E-----------F'--G'    feature
```

I don't want to change `E` (which is actually a long series of commits).

`git rebase --onto D B` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810400/334519)) results in merge conflicts (with or without `--preserve-merges`).

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Something like `git update-ref feature_branch $(git commit-tree -p E -p B -m "fakeout merge" F^{tree})` and then `git cherry-pick G` should work

Comment: @AndrewC to copy the commit message `git show -s --pretty=%B F` | git commit-tree etc.`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most methods will be somewhat painful.  There's a moderately painless version using `git filter-branch`, except that filter-branch itself is painful. :-)  (You'd filter commits `F` and `G` and write a commit-filter that substitutes in the new parents you want for `F'`, and let the filter-branch operation replace the parentage for `G`.)

I think the simplest method that does not resort to low level commands is just to make a new merge, then rebase `G` onto the new merge.  The new merge may have conflicts but we don't care, we just want to take the old merge's tree, which we can do like this:

```
$ git checkout <sha1>  # Use D or E's sha-1 here.
                       # Note: whichever you use will
                       # be the first parent of our new
                       # merge; choose based on that.
$ git merge --no-commit <sha1>  # use the remaining sha-1 here
[ignore resulting stuff]
$ git rm -rf .         # Note: assumes you're in top dir of work tree
$ git checkout <sha1-of-F> -- .
$ git commit           # Create merge commit F'
```

The first `checkout` gets you on a detached HEAD with one SHA-1, the `merge --no-commit` starts the merge process with the other SHA-1, the `git rm -rf .` throws away the merged tree and any conflicts, and the `git checkout <id> -- .` fills in the index and work-tree from the previous merge.  The final `git commit` creates merge `F'` with the same tree as merge `F`, but with different parents.

At this point (still with a detached HEAD) you can rebase (or cherry-pick) commit `G` (or many commits `G`), then force your branch to point to the tip of the new graph.  I'd suggest using `git rebase ... --onto HEAD` but I have not tested this with a detached HEAD and there's at least one way it might go wrong (resolving `HEAD` to an ID too late).

The low level `git commit-tree` command may actually be even simpler.  [Andrew C wrote the correct command in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573000/rebasing-to-change-parent-of-a-merge-commit#comment45456227_28573000), although you have to spell out the branch name with `git update-ref`.  [Edit: maybe not quite correct, the two parents you want are `D` and `E`, not `D` and `B`.  Again, put the one you want as first-parent first.]

The advantage (?) of using the more familiar commands is that they're, well, more familiar.

Comment: Thanks much! I was able to make both approaches work pretty straightforwardly (just using `cherry-pick` for the `G` commits).

Comment: Yup whoops, took the parents from the wrong diagram.

Comment: Thanks anyway @Andrew C—I got what you meant.