# How to create copy of a snapshot (commit) in a branch onto another branch in git?

Tags: git

When I started to use Git, one of the first things I learned about it is that Git does not store information as list of file-based changes (patches), but as a stream of snapshots. A commit is a snapshot of all the repository.

Consider we have two branches in a repository Branch_A and Branch_B. No mater the relation between them, it may be very simple of very complicated (merge with others branches...). Just represent them like this:

```
A <--- ... -- I <----- J <----- K                Branch_A


       M <------ N <----- O <----- P             Branch_B
```

For some reasons, I want that the next commit of Branch_A be exactly the state (the snapshot) of the commit P in Branch_B.

Is there a git command to do this ?

I can't use a "normal" merge, because I don't want to resolv conflicts between P and K.
I can't use a recursive merge with the option "theirs" because it will keep all the files in K that do not conflicts with P, even if they do not exist in P.

I can do it like this :

```
cd /path/to/myrepo;
git checkout Branch_B
cp -R * /path/to/save_branch_b_state
git checkout Branch_A
rm -rf *
cp -R /path/to/save_branch_b_state . (In fact, I copy everything but the .git directory)
git add *
git commit
```

But I imagine there is a git command to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one *single* git command to do it but you can do it with just a few commands.

The first question, though, is: do you want this to at least *resemble* a merge (in which case, it will really be a merge)?  That is, what do you want the commit graph to look like—should it show some kind of linkage from `branch_B` (where commit `P` lives), a la:

```
A <--- ... -- I <----- J <----- K <--- *         Branch_A
                                     /
       M <------ N <----- O <----- P             Branch_B
```

where `*` is your new commit?  Or do you want it to be totally independent?

The low-level command `git commit-tree` will make a new commit with arbitrary parent-age (you supply the parent IDs with `-p`, a message, and an existing "tree" object).  It prints the resulting commit-object ID.  So to do this with the low level command:

```
tree=$(git rev-parse B^{tree})  # or similar to find the tree ID
commit=$(git commit-tree -p ... -m message $tree) # or use -F, or stdin
```

then set `Branch_A` to point to `$commit` (using `git branch` or `git update-ref`).  This can be turned into a one line shell thing and hence done as a git alias, but it's a bit tricky and probably deserves to be a shell script.  Choose just one ID as parent to make your new commit a regular (non-merge) commit, or multiple IDs to make it a merge; if you do make it a merge, choose the parent ID ordering based on how you want `--first-parent` to work in the future.

Or, you can do it with somewhat higher level git commands.  For instance, if you *don't* want it to be (and resemble) a merge, you can simply start on `Branch_A`, erase everything (remove the entire tree from the index and work-tree), repopulate everything from commit `P` (create new index contents and work-tree based on commit `P`), and then commit:

```
$ git checkout Branch_A
$ git rm -rf .                # cd to top dir first if needed
$ git checkout Branch_B -- .  # index and work tree = commit P
$ git commit
```

Or, do the above as a real merge: see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28573000/1256452).

Comment: `git commit-tree` is not designed for casual use, as most people don't have a prepared tree object ready to go, most of the time. :-)  But it's used in `git filter-branch`, which mentions it repeatedly, so once you've done some filter-branches you pick these things up...

Answer (score 0):

In destination branch:
`git cherry-pick <commit id>`

Comment: This will diff `<commit id>` against `<commit id>^` (its parent) and then apply that *change* to the destination branch, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

In destination branch working directory:

```
$ rm -rf *
$ git add .
$ git cherry-pick -n -X theirs <COMMIT_ID>
$ git commit --no-edit
```

*The `rm` command may need to be additionally run for dot (hidden) files (`.*` except `.git`). Because in a typical shell the asterisk (`*`) symbol in the glob pattern does not expand to dot files.*