# git merge and rebase two repositories

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, rebase

I need to merge two git repositories by rebasing the root of the second repository onto the head of the first one.
While doing so, it should keep:

- the commit history
- all author dates + names
- all tags
- unmerged (feature) branches
- merged branches
- the two repositories have common files (same file name) and the content was changed in both repos

How can I achieve this?

This only needs to be done once and I don't need to keep the second repository after the merge.

Note: You can use the linked repositories to test your solution.

---

Here's an example:

**merge-test-first:**

My first (examplary) repository looks like this (https://github.com/Pro/merge-test-first):

```
* fcc6649 (HEAD -> master) J1
| * ba0ecb9 (branch_I1) K1
|/  
* 91bf6a4 I1
* acacd68 (tag: tag_H1) H1
|\  
| * 40bf845 (branch_B1) F1
| * 3ea2925 D1
* | 3780004 G1
| | * f7a61eb (branch_D1) E1
| |/  
| * aae948d C1
|/  
* 739d400 B1
* 6717e64 A1
```

(Output of `git log --oneline --abbrev-commit --all --graph --decorate --color`)

[image: Graph for first repo]

It contains a branch (`branch_B1`) with base `B1` and then merged into master as `H1` and two branches `branch_D1`, `branch_I1`

**merge-test-second:**

The second repository, which should be merged and then rebased onto `merge-test-first/master/HEAD` has some similar structure (https://github.com/Pro/merge-test-second):

```
*   28e726a (HEAD -> master) I2
|\  
| * 46f9d71 (branch_D2) G2
* | 2ae8b4d H2
| | * 606a346 (branch_E2, tag: tag_F2) F2
| |/  
| * bed8db1 E2
|/  
* e94c6d7 (tag: tag_D2) D2
| * 8a98058 (branch_B2) C2
|/  
* 82cb3ee B2
* 1b12fdf A2
```

[image: Graph for second repo]

**Final result should be:**

`A2` from the second repo should be rebased onto `J1` from the first repo, including all the commits, author dates and branches and merges:

```
*   (HEAD -> master) I2
|\  
| * (branch_D2) G2
* | H2
| | * (branch_E2, tag: tag_F2) F2
| |/  
| * E2
|/  
* (tag: tag_D2) D2
| * (branch_B2) C2
|/  
* B2
* A2    
|   
* J1
| * (branch_I1) K1
|/  
* I1
* (tag: tag_H1) H1
|\  
| * (branch_B1) F1
| * D1
* | G1
| | * (branch_D1) E1
| |/  
| * C1
|/  
* B1
* A1
```

So I need to add the red edge somehow (note: the tags are not visible in this graph, but should also be rebased):

[image: final graph]

**What I tried so far:**

1. Simple rebase:
   `git rebase test-first/master test-second/master`
   This doesn't preserve the merges and author dates, nor other branches from the second repo
2. Solution for keeping author dates and merges:
   http://axiac.ro/blog/2014/11/merging-git-repositories/
   Summary: it uses `--preserve-merges` and then some git magic (`git filter-branch ...`) to rewrite the author dates.
   This solution also doesn't copy over all the unmerged branches of the second repo.
3. [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)
   Only merges a single branch
4. [Setting git parent pointer to a different parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810348/setting-git-parent-pointer-to-a-different-parent)
   Git grafs only change the parent, but don't take into account the differences if two files have been changed in both repos and should be merged.

Comment: A piece of advice: don't try to preserve the committer dates. They are changing because the commit is changing and this is future information people want to know. The important thing to preserve is the *author and author date*.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question to use author dates, that's what I meant.

Comment: Do you necessarily want a *rebase*, or is it sufficient to insert a parent link while leaving the attached trees unmodified?  If it *is* sufficient, you just need to create a graft / replace-entry, then run `filter-branch` to copy all the commits (using `--tag-name-filter cat` to re-point tags).

Comment: Both repositories contain some files which have the same name and source and were modified in both repos. So I suppose a rebase is required? Or does the parent link handle this correctly?