# Merging subtree changes - fatal: invalid path 'somefile_BASE_20704.cs'

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree

I have three repos - names changed for clarity:

`SharedStuff`, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`

Both of the projects are using git-subtree to maintain a local copy of `SharedStuff`.  They both have made local changes that I'm trying to merge up centrally, test, then merge back out to each again.

I've run this on the ProjectA repo:

`git subtree split --prefix=SharedStuff -b SharedStuff_from_ProjectA --rejoin`

...then pushed that to the `SharedStuff` repo, resolved a few simple conflicts, merged it up.

Now I've run this on the ProjectB repo:

`git subtree split --prefix=platform/SharedStuff -b SharedStuff_from_Project_B --rejoin`

...and again pushed that to the `SharedStuff` repo in a new branch.  The problem occurs when I'm trying to merge those changes in.

In the current case, I switch to the `SharedStuff_from_Project_B` branch, then `git merge master` - but I immediately get all changed files listed as **add/add** conflicts.  When I run `git mergetool`, each one has an error like this:

```
Merging:
somefile.xyz

Normal merge conflict for 'somefile.xyz':
  {local}: created file
  {remote}: created file
fatal: invalid path './somefile.xyz_BASE_20704.cs'
```

(Of course, if I try the other way around - to merge `SharedStuff_from_Project_B` into `master` - I get the same kinds of conflicts, just reversed.  Still add/add).

My guess is that something might be wrong in ProjectB's history, causing the appearance of add/adds.  I'm not sure how to further diagnose this, though - what can I do?

*Edit*: there was a previous subtree "rejoin" commit in `ProjectB`, but the changes weren't merged into `SharedStuff` at that point it seems.  But, re-running `git subtree split` with `--ignore-joins` produces the same problem - lots of `add/add` merge conflicts, despite the history of that split subtree branch going back to when the `SharedStuff` was first put into `ProjectB`. :(

*Edit*: Also `git merge-base` between the split subtree from `ProjectB` and `master` on `SharedStuff` doesn't give any results.  I'm not sure how this came to be or how to resolve?

Comment: Here we go, bounty #3 ...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what caused this.  However, here's how I resolved it - kind of.  I still want a better answers!

Both 'shared' branches the actual master on `SharedStuff` and the split-off copy from `ProjectB` had a the same commits in their distant history - well, the same changes with the same `tree` SHAs internally, but different commit SHAs.  This is because, somehow, the `ProjectB` branch had a different very first initial commit than `SharedStuff`.

So long as there were no common commits (with the same SHAs) in the history, merging, rebasing etc won't be able to find a common ground and will assume files were added in both histories.

The solution: find two early commits in the history with the same `tree` SHA (i.e. exactly the same file content), and commit info - message, author etc - and manually 'overwrite' the parent of that commit in `ProjectB`'s split branch to the parent in `SharedStuff`'s master.

I did this using a graft: [Setting git parent pointer to a different parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810348/setting-git-parent-pointer-to-a-different-parent)

1. Write a new line to `.git/info/grafts`, basically `wrong-parent right-parent`
2. Switch to the branch - discover PowerShell `echo` used a 16-bit character format, re-save with Sublime Text and switch again ;)
3. Run `git filter-branch right-parent..HEAD` on the branch to seal the deal
4. Verify everything's mergeable

The next fun challenge will be seeing how this version merges back into `ProjectB`; will update when that's done..

**I would still really welcome a real answer to this - this is really hacky!**

Comment: Quick correction: the graft line should actually be `child-of-wrong-parent right-parent`.  But I still don't want to resort to this..