# Introduce merges in grafted Git history

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-filter-branch, .git-info-grafts

I'm currently importing an SVN repository into Git.  The structure of the SVN repository is a bit messy so I'm having to convert it into three separate Git repositories and then merge them all together.

If these was a simple project with three parts to a single history, then I might just rebase them on top of the other, e.g.:

```
cd part3
git remote add -f part1 url_to_part1
git remote add -f part2 url_to_part2
git rebase part2/master
git rebase part1/master
```

However `part3` in my example above contains dozens of tags and three branches.  If parts 1 and 2 had been cleanly merged into `master` (well, trunk) within SVN, then I would do something like [this](http://blog.agavi.org/post/16865375185/fixing-svn-merge-history-in-git-repositories) to graft the branch into the history correctly.  This has the benefit that all of the tags stay in place, unlike with a rebase.

But one of the branches has an orphaned commit that we would now like to merge into the history.  Now if I try to fix the history with the graft, the changes from the orphaned commit are lost.  In the example below, the merge X to C happened in SVN and so I can create the link with a graft.  But I want to merge the orphaned commit O in between C and D, while preserving the tags on commits E, G etc.

```
A-B-C-[ ]-D-E-F-G-H-...  
 \ /  /
  X--O
```

Is there a way that I can specify the graph structure using something like the grafts file but then actually execute the implied merges?  Or is there a filter-branch command that I should be using here?

Comment: The [note on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810348/setting-git-parent-pointer-to-a-different-parent/3811028#3811028) suggests this isn't possible with grafts.  Guess I'll have to rebase and then manually move the tags.

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

You will be able to write the rules file in a way that you can convert your whole SVN repository in one very performant run to a proper Git repository.

Comment: To clarify, I am using svn2git with three different sets of parameters against one SVN repository and then trying to stitch the results together (because a single svn2git command doesn't fit the non-standard layout of the SVN repo).

Comment: To clarify, you are **not** using the svn2git utility I recommended, otherwise you wouldn't have to jump hoops like you are trying to do. ;-)