# Convert multiple hg repositories to single git repository with multiple branches

Tags: git, mercurial

I am switching to git from Mercurial and have been using [hg-fast-export](http://hivelogic.com/articles/converting-from-mercurial-to-git) successfully.  Now I have a tricky situation.  I have a project which is using separate hg repositories per-branch and I want to convert these to a single git repository with 'proper' branches, keeping my hg changesets if possible.

So the current structure looks like this - each folder is an hg repository:

```
Project-v1.0
Project-v2.0
Project-v3.0
```

I want to end up with a single git repository called 'Project' that contains 3 branches, v1.0, v2.0 and v3.0.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the hg repositories are clones from one base repo, you can use the [hggit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgGit) extension to export them into one git repo. Say your branches live in the directories b1/, b2/ and b3/, then all you need is to

```
cd b1; mkdir ../gb1 && git init --bare ../gb1 && hg push ../gb1; cd ..
cd b2; mkdir ../gb1 && git init --bare ../gb2 && hg push ../gb2; cd ..
cd b3; mkdir ../gb1 && git init --bare ../gb3 && hg push ../gb3; cd ..
# now you have one git repo for each hg branch

cd gb1
git remote add gb2 ../gb2
git remote add gb3 ../gb3
git fetch --all
# now you have all branches in the gb1 repo
rm -r ../gb2 ../gb3
# the other repos are now not used anymore
```

If the different hg repos are unrelated, you have to use the graft point solution which VonC mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with:

- creating 3 distinct Git repos from the three Mercurial ones
- importing `Project-v2.0` history into `Project-v1.0` Git repo (by adding `Project-v2.0` as a remote and fetching it in a '`v2.0`' branch: 2 distinct roots are created)
  And, through a **[graft point](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint)**, linking the two branches together (the `HEAD` of `v1.0` branch becomes the parent of the first commit of `v2.0` branch).
- using [`filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to make those graft points permanent (i.e. not limited to your repo)

(repeat for the `Project-v3.0`, fetch into the first one into a separate `v3.0` branch, grafted to the `HEAD` of `v2.0` branch, and filter-branch to make the graft permanent)

You have a similar scenario (although it is about "prepend some history", not "append") in the SO question "[How to prepend the past to a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147097/how-to-prepend-the-past-to-a-git-repository)".