# Remove the last line from a file in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, truncate

I have a file, `foo.txt`, containing the following lines:

```
a
b
c
```

I want a simple command that results in the contents of `foo.txt` being:

```
a
b
```

Answer (score 588, accepted):

Using [`GNU sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/):

```
sed -i '$ d' foo.txt
```

The `-i` option does not exist in `GNU sed` versions older than 3.95, so you have to use it as a filter with a temporary file:

```
cp foo.txt foo.txt.tmp
sed '$ d' foo.txt.tmp > foo.txt
rm -f foo.txt.tmp
```

Of course, in that case you could also use `head -n -1` instead of `sed`.

**MacOS:**

On Mac OS X (as of 10.7.4), the equivalent of the `sed -i` command above is

```
sed -i '' -e '$ d' foo.txt
```

Comment: On Mac OS X (as of 10.7.4), the equivalent of the `sed -i` command above is `sed -i '' -e '$ d' foo.txt`. Also, `head -n -1` won't currently work on a Mac.

Comment: Could you explain what '$ d' regex does? It's question about removing last line, so I think this is the most important part for everyone viewing this question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Miro : By no means is `$ d` a regex. It is a sed command. `d` is the command for deleting a line, while `$` means "the last line in the file". When specifying a location (called "range" in sed lingo) before a command, that command is only applied to the specified location. So, this command explicitly says "in the range of the last line in a file, delete it". Quite slick and straight to the point, if you ask me.

Comment: How do your remove the last line but only if it's an empty line?

Comment: which versions of `sed` is the `-i` option compatible with?

Comment: @Alex: updated for GNU sed; no idea about the various BSD/UNIX/MacOS sed versions...

Comment: When there are multiple empty lines at the end of the file, this seems to remove the last two empty lines instead of last one empty line.

Comment: As @skan and Panu Haaramo note, this has problems with empty lines at the end

Answer (score 380):

This is by far the fastest and simplest solution, especially on big files:

```
head -n -1 foo.txt > temp.txt ; mv temp.txt foo.txt
```

if You want to delete the top line use this:

```
tail -n +2 foo.txt
```

which means output lines starting at line 2.

Do not use `sed` for deleting lines from the top or bottom of a file -- it's very very slow if the file is large.

Comment: `head -n -1 foo.txt` is enough

Comment: head -n -1 doesn't work on bdsutils' head. at least not in the version macos is using, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @johannes_lalala On Mac, you can `brew install coreutils` (GNU core utilities) and use `ghead` instead of `head`.

Comment: Here is a simple bash script that automates it in case you have multiple files with different number of lines at the bottom to delete: cat TAILfixer `FILE=$1; TAIL=$2; head -n -${TAIL} ${FILE} > temp ; mv temp ${FILE}` Run it for deleting 4 lines for instance from myfile as: `./TAILfixer myfile 4` of course first make it executable by `chmod +x TAILfixer`

Comment: Thumbs up because it worked, but for all the comparison to `sed`, this command is pretty darn slow as well

Comment: this soulution is not working when the last line is empty as I see. It deleted the last non-empty line and left the last line which is an empty line. I actually wanted to delete that empty line but I failed with this.

Answer (score 160):

#### For large files

I had trouble with all the answers here because I was working with a HUGE file (~300Gb) and none of the solutions scaled. Here's my solution:

```
filename="example.txt"

file_size="$(stat --format=%s "$filename")"
trim_count="$(tail -n1 "$filename" | wc -c)"
end_position="$(echo "$file_size - $trim_count" | bc)"

dd if=/dev/null of="$filename" bs=1 seek="$end_position"
```

Or alternatively, as a one liner:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=<filename> bs=1 seek=$(echo $(stat --format=%s <filename> ) - $( tail -n1 <filename> | wc -c) | bc )
```

In words: Find out the length of the file you want to end up with (length of file minus length of length of its last line, using `bc`), and set that position to be the end of the file (by `dd`ing one byte of  `/dev/null` onto it).

This is fast because `tail` starts reading from **the end**, and `dd` will overwrite the file **in place** rather than copy (and parse) every line of the file, which is what the other solutions do.

**NOTE: This removes the line from the file in place! Make a backup or test on a dummy file before trying it out on your own file!**

Comment: I didn't even know about dd. This should be the top answer. Thank you so much! It's a shame the solution does not work for (block) gzipped files.

Comment: Very, very clever approach! Just a note: it requires and operates on an real file, so it can not be used on pipes, command substitutions, redirections and such chains.

Comment: This should be the top answer. Worked instantly for my ~8 GB file.

Comment: mac users: dd if=/dev/null of=<filename> bs=1 seek=$(echo $(stat -f=%z <filename> | cut -c 2- ) - $( tail -n1 <filename> | wc -c) | bc )

Comment: This approach is the way to go for large files!

Comment: Can we test somehow if the last line is empty?

Comment: @Lanti: run tail -n1 on the file and take a look!

Comment: I desperately scrolled through previous 2 answers that propose using `sed` and `head`+`>`, and YEAH, exactly what I needed, finally, thanks much! **Must be the top answer, totally agree!**

Comment: You can also calculate the number of bytes to remove with bash directly: `end_position=$(($file_size - $trim_count))`

Comment: Can confirm alternative calculation of the number of bytes is working. Was helpful to me because: `-bash: bc: command not found` (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 84):

To remove the last line from a file **without reading the whole file or rewriting anything**, you can use

```
tail -n 1 "$file" | wc -c | xargs -I {} truncate "$file" -s -{}
```

To remove the last line and also print it on stdout ("pop" it), you can combine that command with `tee`:

```
tail -n 1 "$file" | tee >(wc -c | xargs -I {} truncate "$file" -s -{})
```

These commands can efficiently process a very large file.  This is similar to, and inspired by, Yossi's answer, but it avoids using a few extra functions.

If you're going to use these repeatedly and want error handling and some other features, you can use the `poptail` command here:
https://github.com/donm/evenmoreutils

Comment: Quick note: `truncate` is not available on OS X by default. But it's easy to install using Brew: `brew install truncate`.

Comment: Very nice. Much better without dd. I was terrified of using dd as a single misplaced digit or letter can spell disaster.. +1

Comment: (JOKE WARNING) Actually, ("dd" --> "disaster") requires 1 substitution and 6 insertions; hardly "a single misplaced digit or letter". :)

Comment: Question, how is `tail | wc` not reading the whole file?

Comment: @malavv tail reads backwards from the end of the file looking for newlines....

Answer (score 47):

On **macOS**, `head -n -1` wont work but you can use this command:

```bash
cat file.txt | tail -r | tail -n +2 | tail -r
```

1. `tail -r` reverses the order of lines in its input
2. `tail -n +2` prints all the lines starting from the second line in its input

Comment: Installing coreutils using Homebrew will give you the GNU head as 'ghead', allowing you to do `ghead -n -1`

Answer (score 33):

> Mac Users

if you only want the last line deleted output without changing the file itself do

`sed -e '$ d' foo.txt`

if you want to delete the last line of the input file itself do

`sed -i '' -e '$ d' foo.txt`

Comment: This works for me but I don't understand. anyhow, it worked.

Comment: The flag `-i ''` tells sed to modify file in-place, while keeping a backup in a file with the extension provided as a parameter. Since the parameter is an empty string, no backup file is created. `-e` tells sed to execute a command. The command `$ d` means: find the last line (`$`) and delete it (`d`).

Answer (score 17):

```
echo -e '$d\nw\nq'| ed foo.txt
```

Comment: For a filter solution that does not edit the file in place, use `sed '$d'`.

Answer (score 15):

### Linux

`$` means the last line, and `d` means delete:

```
sed '$d' ~/path/to/your/file/name
```

### MacOS

Equivalent of the `sed -i`:

```
sed -i '' -e '$ d' ~/path/to/your/file/name
```

Answer (score 14):

```
awk 'NR>1{print buf}{buf = $0}'
```

Essentially, this code says the following:

For each line after the first, print the buffered line

for each line, reset the buffer

The buffer is lagged by one line, hence you end up printing lines 1 to n-1

Comment: This solution is a filter and does not edit the file in place.

Comment: POSIX compiant and most cross-platform and cross-shell

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using sponge (from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package):

```
head -n -1 foo.txt | sponge foo.txt
```

Summary of solutions:

1. If you want a fast solution for large files, use the [efficient tail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043281/1376404) or [dd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17794626/1376404) approach.
2. If you want something easy to extend/tweak and portable, use the [redirect and move](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12349094/1376404) approach.
3. If you want something easy to extend/tweak, the file is not too large, portability (i.e., depending on `moreutils` package) is not an issue, *and* you are a fan of square pants, consider the sponge approach.

A nice benefit of the sponge approach, compared to "redirect and move" approaches, is that sponge preserves file permissions.

Sponge uses considerably more RAM compared to the "redirect and move" approach. This gains a bit of speed (only about 20%), but if you're interested in speed the "efficient tail" and dd approaches are the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

OK processing a good amount of data and the output was OK, but had one junk line.

If I piped the output of the script to:

| sed -i '$ d'   I would get the following error and finally no output at all
sed: no input files

But  | head -n -1   worked!

Answer (score 1):

Both of these solutions are here in other forms. I found these a little more practical, clear, and useful:

Using dd:

```
BADLINESCOUNT=1
ORIGINALFILE=/tmp/whatever
dd if=${ORIGINALFILE} of=${ORIGINALFILE}.tmp status=none bs=1 count=$(printf "$(stat --format=%s ${ORIGINALFILE}) - $(tail -n${BADLINESCOUNT} ${ORIGINALFILE} | wc -c)\n" | bc )
/bin/mv -f ${ORIGINALFILE}.tmp ${ORIGINALFILE}
```

Using truncate:

```
BADLINESCOUNT=1
ORIGINALFILE=/tmp/whatever
truncate -s $(printf "$(stat --format=%s ${ORIGINALFILE}) - $(tail -n${BADLINESCOUNT} ${ORIGINALFILE} | wc -c)\n" | bc ) ${ORIGINALFILE}
```

Comment: Ouch. Way too complicated.

Comment: It's long but simplistic in my opinion: modular, human readable, reusable code that can handle massive files and with no obscene bash-isms, sed version requirements, or unavailable packages.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last line in the zshrc file for example:

```bash
cat ~/.zshrc
sed -i '' -e '$ d' ~/.zshrc
cat ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk "NR != `wc -l < text.file`" text.file &> newtext.file
```

This snippet does the trick.

Comment: This just erases the whole file for me.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this method also : example of removing last n number of lines.**

> a=0 ; while [ $a -lt 4 ];do sed -i '$ d' output.txt; a=`expr $a + 1`;done

**Removing last 4 lines from file(output.txt).**

Answer (score -6):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN{prv=""};print prv ; prv=$_;' file
```