# Bash working code to delete first or last line from file

Tags: bash, line

I saw the `sed` examples, but no matter how I write that it won't delete my first line.  Actually, I did more tests and it won't delete my first line either, so for sure I'm doing something wrong:

```
sed '1d' filename
```

or for last line

```
sed '$d' file name
```

I want the changes to take place in the same file, and don't want another output file.
So please, what's the correct way to remove the last line in my file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash - remove the last line from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/bash-remove-the-last-line-from-a-file)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`sed -i '$ d' filename`. The `-i` flag edits file in place.

Comment: This deletes the last line. To delete the first line, use `sed -i '1,1d' filename`.

Comment: @skolima The second address is superflous; just `1d` is sufficient.

Answer (score 15):

Here you go !
delete first line (also BSD/MacOS compatible)

```
sed '1,1d' file1  >> file1.out
```

delete last row/line

```
sed '$d' file2  >> file2.out
```

Comment: Nice answer. I pretty much concatenate both as follows: `sed "1,1d; $d" file1 > file2`

Answer (score 7):

If your sed supports in-place editing, it's `sed -e '1d' -e '$d' -i filename`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `--in-place` (`-i`) switch:

```
sed -i '$d' filename
```

Source: [man sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

Answer (score 3):

Because nobody gives it any love:

```
ed filename <<'END'
1d
$d
w
q
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Giving this answer since `sed` is not tagged.

```
head -`wc -l test2.cc | awk '{print ($1-1)}'` test2.cc
```

Comment: This is not compatible with BSD version of head (MacOS)

Comment: And reading the entire file twice just to get the argument to pass to `head` is ... wacky. The entire thing could be done in just Awk with a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cat file1 | sed "1,1d; $d" > file2`