# Reading everything but first and last line into a string in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read a .csr file into a string, but I don't want the first and last line of the file.

I've tried reading the file into a  string and then splitting it into an array, but I can't get the syntax to work.

I've also tried reading it into a string and then stripping away the first and last line (they never change), but I've had the same issue.

I'm new to bash and just need this script written, any help would be appreciated.

The file is test.csr and looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
TESTESTESTESTESTESTSETESTEESSTSETESTTESTES
TESTESTESTESTESTESTSETESTEESSTSETESTTESTES
...
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

As an attempt for stripping I used

```
csrFile=`cat server.csr`
#echo "$csrFile"
#csrFile=${csrFile##*-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----  }
#csrFile=${csrFile%% -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----*}
#echo "$csrFile"
```

But when I echoed this out, the entire string was still intact

My attempt for splitting into an array

```
readarray -t my_array <<<"$csrFile"
echo "$my_array"
echo "$csrFile"
( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${csrFile[*]}" )
```

But this didn't print anything out

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Bash working code to delete first or last line from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8234711/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` would be ideal for this job.

To strip off the first and final lines, use

```
sed '1d;$d' server.csr
```

Or if you'd like to be more precise, try

```
sed '/-----\(BEGIN\|END\) CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----/d'  server.csr
```

To read the result into a variable, use the shell `$()` syntax:

```
csrfile=$(sed '/-----\(BEGIN\|END\) CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----/d'  server.csr)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, how can I read the sed into a variable?
my attempt is:  
    csrString = sed '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----/d;/-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----/d'  server.csr
    
echo "$csrString"

Comment: Managed it with 
csrFilteredString=$(echo "$a" | sed '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----/d;/-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----/d'  server.csr)
echo "$csrFilteredString"

Answer (score 0):

A more portable way would be to use tool that actually can read CSR, like `openssl`:

```
openssl req -in server.csr -outform der | base64 -w64
```

`-outform der` encodes the CSR into binary (actually ASN1)

`base64 -w64` gets it back to base64 with 64 characters per line