# How to delete first two lines and last four lines from a text file with bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to delete first two lines and last four lines from my text files. How can I do this with Bash?

Comment: The following may help you with deleting lines at the end of the file: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/bash-remove-the-last-line-from-a-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/bash-remove-the-last-line-from-a-file)

Comment: I am looking how to do this in place (without using a second file)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can combine [tail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) and [head](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head):

```
$ tail -n +3 file.txt | head -n -4 > file.txt.new && mv file.txt.new file.txt
```

Comment: Note that from Git Bash under Windows, `tail -n +3` works but `head -n -4` tells `invalid number of lines`. Seems like a bug (perhaps an old version of `head` is used).

Comment: bsd-utils' head can't have negative numbers to -n, so this doesn't work on bsd and macos.

Comment: If you have a large file and want to watch progress, use `$ pv file.txt | tail -n +3 | head -n -4 > file.txt.new && mv file.txt.new file.txt`.  You'll get a handy progress meter.

Comment: slightly tangential comment: i just came across a util that is similar to `tail` called Debian `buthead`, which more people should have the chance to enjoy: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/buthead/buthead.1.en.html  (it outputs all "but head"... as in "all but N lines from the head")

Comment: With `brew` on macOs you can install `coreutils` this will install GNU core utils including head or tail, the binary are prefixed with `g` to avoid collision with system utils. So simply prepending `g` to the above answer should work `gtail -n +3 file.txt | ghead -n -4 > file.txt.new && mv file.txt.new file.txt`.

Answer (score 21):

**Head and Tail**

```
cat input.txt | tail -n +3 | head -n -4
```

**Sed Solution**

```
cat input.txt | sed '1,2d' | sed -n -e :a -e '1,4!{P;N;D;};N;ba'
```

Comment: You don't need to use `cat`: `tail -n +3 input.txt | ...` works perfectly (and the same for `sed`).

Comment: Thank you for the sed solution; I needed it on a machine that doesn't allow negative line numbers for head.  (The 4 in the first command should be negated, by the way.)

Answer (score 14):

This is the quickest way I found:

```
sed -i 1,2d filename
```

Comment: `-i extension  
             Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-
             length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.`

Comment: That's what the documentation says, at least the implementation of sed on my system…

Comment: sorry, you are right. I didn't realize, because osx's bsdutils-sed doesn't know -i

Comment: @johannes_lalala: `-i` is a GNU-`sed` feature.

Comment: This only deletes the first two lines, but the last four should also be deleted.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I must have missed the last bit! I suppose the command might be combined with the `head` command, as suggested in the above reply. I'm gonna update my answer.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't really work, so the best solution remains the one suggested by @Debaditya above.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the ex editor from the bash command line using the following sample. Note it uses a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to end the list of commands to ex.

```
ex text.file << EOF
1,2d
$
-3,.d
x
EOF
```