# remove first text with shell script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh, cut

Please someone help me with this bash script,
lets say I have lots of files with url like below:

```
https://example.com/x/c-ark4TxjU8/mybook.zip
https://example.com/x/y9kZvVp1k_Q/myfilename.zip
```

My question is, how to remove all other text and leave only the file name?

I've tried to use the command described in this url [How to delete first two lines and last four lines from a text file with bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460919/how-to-delete-first-two-lines-and-last-four-lines-from-a-text-file-with-bash)

But since the text is random which means it doesn't have exact numbers the code is not working.

Comment: `sed 's;.*/;;' file`

Comment: nice! thanks a lot Avinash Raj , problem solved!

Comment: using only bash or sh: say that var `x` has such a line, then `echo ${x##*/}`   gives you the file name part (`##patern` removes the longest match of (shell-)pattern from the var).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *sed* utility to parse out just the filenames

```
sed 's_.*\/__'
```

Comment: If you use `_` as the delimiter, you don't need to escape the `/`.

Comment: Thanks Yaitzme, i can use that sed command too , thanks a lot

Comment: Oh yeah, there's gonna be just one filename per line.

Comment: Last two underscores are hard to distinguish. You may use another delimiter.

Comment: @Yaitzme no, because `.*/` should match from the start upto the last forward slash. So there must be single match per line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

The easiest way that I find:

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file.txt
```

or

```
awk -F/ '{print $6}' file.txt
```

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed 's;.*/;;' file.txt
```

You can use `cut`:

```
cut -d'/' -f6 file.txt
```

Comment: you forget grep, `grep -o '[^/]+$' file`

Comment: I'm not convinced about the cut command or the equivalent use of awk. The important part is to print the _last_ field, not the 6th.

Comment: Yes but there is awk solutions also that print last column @TomFenech

Comment: I can see that, my point is that the solutions using a fixed field don't really add anything useful to your answer.