# Fix format of VERY LARGE json file

Tags: python, json, large-files

I have a 1.5G JSON file.  It is supposed to contain an array of objects, however there is an extra comma after the last object in the array.

```
selah@wwbp:~$ tail -n4 /data/selah/diabetes_tweets.json 
    "type": "retweet:reply", 
    "citation_url": "http://twitter.com/Garthicus/status/5903085804"
},
]
```

I tried editing with VI and some other text editors but they all froze.  Is there an easy programmatic way to remove this comma with python?

Comment: Personally, I would truncate the file to be 3 chars shorter then just append write the \n and ] back onto it http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_truncate.htm

Comment: In general, open the file, seek to the end, start reading backwards until you find the first comma, then remove it by pasting the text you've read so far to the position before the current cursor.

Comment: Are you sure you need to remove the character at all? Trailing commas are permitted in some languages. Ex. In Python, `[1,2,3,]` is valid syntax.

Comment: @Kevin the formal JSON standard does not allow a trailing comma. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object).

Comment: @Selah how was the file generated? It'd be easier to fix it in the first place.

Comment: it was generated from a script that makes API requests... it takes hours to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to remove the last two lines `head -n -2 myfile.txt > myfile_fix.txt` then `echo '}' >> myfile_fix.txt
 echo ']' >> myfile_fix.txt` to add back what you need.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on a mac: `head: illegal line count -- -2`. Maybe in a different shell `-2` works? Also, I thought `head` would only print the lines.

Anyway this solution relates to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/bash-remove-the-last-line-from-a-file

Comment: "Note that this works with some versions of head, but is not standard. Indeed, the standard for head states: The application shall ensure that the number option-argument is a positive decimal integer." - http://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell

Comment: Maybe a more robust solution would be to use wc to get the number of lines and then subtract 2?  However -n -2 worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this with the following Node.js script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8');
console.log(JSON.stringify(eval("(" + data + ")")));
```

node fix.js your.json