# Linux: Pipe `find` text file list | `dos2unix` | `dd` command

Tags: bash, pipe, ubuntu-14.04

What I'm attempting to do:

- Line 1: find any .txt or .TXT file and pipe them into next command
- Line 2: convert the .txt file to unix format (get rid of Windows line endings)
- Line 3: delete the last line of the file, which is always blank

```
find "${TEMPDIR}" -name *.[Tt][Xx][Tt] | /
xargs dos2unix -k | /
dd if=/dev/null of="$_" bs=1 seek=$(echo $(stat --format=%s "$_" ) - $( tail -n1 "$_" | wc -c) | bc )
```

I can't pipe the (**EDIT** <strike>output</strike>) filename of `xargs dos2unix -k | /` into the third line, I get the following error:

```
stat: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
tail: cannot open '' for reading: No such file or directory
dd: failed to open '': No such file or directory
```

Clearly Iv'e wrongly assumed that `"$_"` will be enough to pass the output through the pipe.

How can I pipe the output (a text file) from `xargs dos2unix -k` into the third line, `dd if=/dev/null of="$_" bs=1 seek=$(echo $(stat --format=%s "$_" ) - $( tail -n1 "$_" | wc -c) | bc )`?

The solution for line 3 comes from an answer to another question on SO about removing the last line from a file, with this answer in particular being touted as a good solution for large files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17794626/893766

Comment: The `dos2unix` program doesn't produce any output, so neither will `xargs dos2unix -k`. It just converts the files silently.

Comment: You can also use `find -iname` for case-insesitive search

Comment: Just don't pipe it, it edits the files in place. Use `;` instead and then continue what your doing.

Comment: Thanks for `-iname` flag

Comment: The `dd` command needs to run on the file you are attempting to modify -- the question you link to specifically cautions about this.  Thus, it cannot be run at the end of a pipeline, because there is no file name to edit.

Comment: The slashes after the pipe characters are syntax errors.  You probably meant to use backslashes, but they aren't necessary here, either -- the shell knows that a pipeline followed by nothing is a multi-line command which continues on the next line.

Comment: I had a nasty bug in my shell script that fixes broken links in `m3u`  files. It turns out the m3u files on my computer that predate me switching from Mac to Windows were using the Windows carriage returns. The hard part is - most modern Mac text editors are smart and hide the special characters Windows uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can this help?

```
find "${TEMPDIR}" -iname '*.txt' -exec dos2unix "{}" \; -exec sed -i '$d' "{}" \;
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could supply multiple `-exec` arguments to `find`.

Comment: This is fine, provided that you drop the quotes around `{}`. :)

Comment: ^^ I don't understand. Having quotes around `{}` is wrong, or unnecessary? I tested with a simple `echo` as command & it gave expected results... `find . -exec echo "#{}#" \;`

Comment: @tripleee: I didn't know either. Earlier I had combined `-exec` with `-print0` for pipe-lining. So I tried this & it worked.

Comment: `find` already does any necessary escaping of the file name when you pass it with `-exec {}` (or rather, it is not exposed to the shell at all, so no escaping is necessary or useful).  But the quotes are consumed by the shell, so they are basically harmless here.

Comment: @tripleee: But putting quotes around `{}` doesn't do anything to the *filename*, quoting or otherwise - It won't even reach the `find` process. The quotes just "protect" the `{}` arriving at the `find` process - of course, no such protection is needed, but nor is any harm done :)

Comment: @psmears Quite so.  "Basically harmless here."

Answer (score 2):

You can try to substitute `dos2unix` with an explicit replace:

```
find "${TEMPDIR}" -iname '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; |
tr -d '\r' |
...
```

As the windows for new line is `\r\n` you remove all the occurrences of `\r` with the command `tr`.

About the `find` command you can use the option `-iname` for case-insensitive search and the `-exec` to run a command.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you experience issues you can use different commands. perl surely can handle code pages. Have a look a this page http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/

Answer (score 1):

If the file is really big, you are already messing up the efficiency by rewriting it with `tr`.  Then, you are reading it a second time with `tail` just to get the index of the last line.

The least inefficient fix I can come up with is to replace `dos2unix` and `dd` with just one command which performs both functions, so you only read and write the output file once.

```
find "$TMPDIR" -iname '*.txt' -exec perl -i -ne '
    print $line if defined $line; ($line = $_) =~ s/\015$//' {} \;
```

Your attempt to use `$_` for the current file name doesn't work.  The value of `$_` is the last file name used by the previous *completed* command; but in the middle of a pipeline, nothing is yet completed.  One possible workaround (which I include only for illustration, not as a recommended solution) would be to run everything in `xargs` where you have access to `{}`, similarly to how it works in `find -exec`.

```
find "$TMPDIR" -iname '*.txt' -print0 |
xargs -r0 sh -c 'dos2unix -k "{}"
    if=/dev/null of="{}" bs=1 seek=$(
        echo $(stat --format=%s "{}" ) - $( tail -n1 "{}" | wc -c) | bc)
```

I added `-print0` and the corresponding `xargs -0` as well as `xargs -r` as illustrations of good form; though the zero-terminated text format is a GNU `find` extension not generally found on other platforms.

(Privately, I would probably also replace the `seek` calculation with a simple Awk script, rather than expend three processes on performing a subtraction.)