# curl error with brew install php56 --with-cgi

Tags: curl, homebrew

After running the following commands, I get a curl error on OSX Yosemite. I can use brew in others but not for php56. I can download from `https://www.php.net/get/php-5.6.10.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror` but not through curl. How can I fix the problem?

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew options php56
brew install --with-cgi php56

==> Installing php56 from homebrew/homebrew-php
==> Downloading https://www.php.net/get/php-5.6.10.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
Error: Failed to download resource "php56"
Download failed: https://www.php.net/get/php-5.6.10.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
```

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was temporarily [disabling certificate verification for all curl requests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109649/63010) by

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

then running my trusted `brew install` and then...

**Don't forget to go back to safety in the end** ([delete the last line from `~./curlrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881990/978502)).