# What is the Exact Use and Meaning of "IFS=!"

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I was trying to understand the usage of IFS but there is something I couldn't find any information about.

My example code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# (C) 2016 Ergin Bilgin

IFS=!
for LINE in $(last -a | sed '$ d')
do
    echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'
done
unset IFS
```

I use this code to print last users line by line. I totally understand the usage of IFS and in this example when I use default IFS, it reads word by word inside of my loop. And when I use `IFS=!` it reads line by line as I wish. The problem here is I couldn't find anything about that "!" on anywhere. I don't remember where I learned that. When I google about achieving same kind of behaviour, I see other values which are usually strings.

So, what is the meaning of that "!" and how it gives me the result I wish?

Thanks

Comment: You can likely replace all of that code with `last -a | awk 'NF>8{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, if the output of `last` had a `!`, the script would split the input lines on that character.

The output format of `last` is not standardized (not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for instance), but you are unlikely to find a system where the first column contains anything but the name of whatever initiated an action.  For instance, I see this:

```
tom      pts/8        Wed Apr 27 04:25   still logged in    michener.jexium-island.net
tom      pts/0        Wed Apr 27 04:15   still logged in    michener.jexium-island.net
reboot   system boot  Wed Apr 27 04:02 - 04:35  (00:33)     3.2.0-4-amd64
tom      pts/0        Tue Apr 26 16:23 - down   (04:56)     michener.jexium-island.net
```

continuing to

```
reboot   system boot  Fri Apr  1 15:54 - 19:03  (03:09)     3.2.0-4-amd64
tom      pts/0        Fri Apr  1 04:34 - down   (00:54)     michener.jexium-island.net

wtmp begins Fri Apr  1 04:34:26 2016
```

with Linux, and different date-formats, origination, etc., on other machines.

By setting `IFS=!`, the script sets the field-separator to a value which is *unlikely* to occur in the output of `last`, so each line is read into `LINE` without splitting it.  Normally, lines are split on spaces.

However, as you see, the output of `last` normally uses spaces for separating columns, and it is fed into `awk` which splits the line anyway — with spaces.  The script could be simplified in various ways, e.g.,:

```
#!/bin/sh

for LINE in $(last -a | sed -e '$ d' -e 's/ .*//')
do    
    echo $LINE
done
```

which is (starting from the example in the question) adequate if the number of logins is not large enough to exceed your command-line.  While checking for variations in `last` output, I noticed one machine with about 9800 lines from several years.  (The other usual motivations given for not using for-loops are implausible in this instance).  As a pipe:

```
#!/bin/sh

last -a | sed -e 's/ .*//' -e '/^$/d' | while IFS= read LINE
do
    echo $LINE
done
```

I changed the sed expression (which OP likely copied from some place such as *[Bash - remove the last line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/bash-remove-the-last-line-from-a-file)*) because it does not work.

Finally, using the `-a` option of `last` is unnecessary, since all of the additional information it provides is discarded.

Comment: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 2):

`IFS=!` is merely setting a non-existent value for `IFS` so that you can iterate input line by line. Having said that using for loop here is not recommended, better to use `read` in a `while` loop like this to print first column i.e. username:

```
last | sed '$ d' | while read -r u _; do
   echo "$u"
done
```