# Delete last blank line from a file and save the file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

How can I delete the last line of a file without reading the entire file or rewriting it in any temp file? I tried to use `sed` but it reads the entire file into memory which is not feasible.

I want to remove the blank line from the end and save the change to the same file.

Since the file is very big and reading through the complete file would be slow, I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

simple sed command to delete last line:

```
sed '$d' <file>
```

here in sed $ is the last line.

You can try awk command:

```
awk 'NR > 1{print t} {t = $0}END{if (NF) print }' file
```

Using cat:

```
cat file.txt | head -n -1 > new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
sed -i '${/^$/d}' filename
```

edited to delete only blank end line.

Your only option not using `sed` that won't read the entire file is to `stat` the file to get the size and then use `dd` to skip to the end before you start reading. However, telling `sed` to only operate on the last line, does essentially that.

Comment: sed -i -u ... -u mean *unbuffered*, so lower memory use

Comment: In this case since you are jumping to the end, you would certainly want to use a buffered read to speed the process, especially for large files.

Comment: buffered speed the process of writing but the problem is memory here, not process speed says OP

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "${/^$/d}": extra characters at the end of d command`.

Comment: It is necessary to put a semicolon at the end of 'd', otherwise you will get @IulianOnofrei error

Comment: For me, only [`sed -i '.txt' '${/^$/d;}' test.txt`](https://www.mkyong.com/mac/sed-command-hits-undefined-label-error-on-mac-os-x/) worked, because after adding the semicolon it failed with `sed: 1: "test.txt": undefined label 'est.txt'`.

Comment: [`sed -i '' '${/^$/d;}' test.txt`](https://mpdaugherty.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/difference-with-sed-in-place-editing-on-mac-os-x-vs-linux/) also works.

Comment: Yes, that would work too. Good comment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

[Remove the last line from a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/remove-the-last-line-from-a-file-in-bash)

Edit: I tested

```
dd if=/dev/null of=<filename> bs=1 seek=$(echo $(stat --format=%s <filename> ) - $( tail -n1 <filename> | wc -c) | bc )
```

and it does what you want