# How to write a dataframe to JSON without a new line character at the end of the file?

Tags: json, pyspark

Currently I have a piece of code which writes a pyspark dataframe to JSON format:

```
output_df = transform(dfs) \
       .withColumn('ingestion_time', lit(datetime.strptime(args["IngestionTime"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))).coalesce(1) \
       .write.json('result', mode="overwrite", ignoreNullFields=False)
```

However the output JSON output file contains an extra line at the end of the file as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

What I need is for the file to end on the last JSON object, not the line after the last JSON object. Like so:
[image]

Is this possible to achieve using dataframe.write.json?

I know there is a lineSep parameter, but I have no issue with the line separation for all objects before the last line.. I just want the end of the file to be on the final JSON object.

Comment: Why is that so important=

Comment: @Clashsoft The file is used as input for some external testing which throws an error if there is extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace the line breaks with empty spaces inside your dataframe.

```
output_df = transform(dfs) \
   .withColumn('ingestion_time', lit(datetime.strptime(args["IngestionTime"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))).coalesce(1) 

output_df = output_df.replace('/n', '')
   
output_df.write.json('result', mode="overwrite", ignoreNullFields=False)
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference to the output sadly.. Apparently the extra line at the end of the JSON output file is a common issue when using DataFrame.write.json in PySpark. By default, it writes each JSON object on a separate line..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249274/delete-last-blank-line-from-a-file-and-save-the-file  . Can you pipe your files through a sed command. ??