# Edit a .csv without read the whole file (python)

Tags: python, csv

I am currently working with data cleaning. I need to clean a big csv file with a few head rows and the last row need to be chopped off. Is there any way I can just chopped the rows without load the whole file?

Comment: `Is there any way` <- Yes there is. However, without knowing what's deficient about your solution, we're not going to be able to help you come up with a better solution

Comment: You could do it through bash. Maybe see [last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/remove-the-last-line-from-a-file-in-bash) / [first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is line oriented, right down into the interpreter.
I think that the best way to do this would be to `sys.call` and using an external program that is better suited for file level manipulations.  This is not cheating, python is a great scripting language.  You should use the unix tools.

[Remove lines from file with head, tail, or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script)

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed this from another similar thread, it should resolve your issue:

```
for line in reversed(open("filename").readlines()):
    print line.rstrip()
```

And in Python 3:

```
for line in reversed(list(open("filename"))):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Note: this does load the whole file. I'm not sure of any way to not do that, so maybe someone else can provide a better solution.