# How can I remove the last empty line in diff file?

Tags: bash, diff, patch

I'm patching my and creating a diff file through this command:

```
diff a my_patch > sw.diff
```

Here `"a"` is my first file, my_patch is a patch.

So now I have `sw.diff` file with differences.
But there's an extra line down there at the end of the file:

```
< an armored space station with enough power to destroy an entire planet.
8d10
< Pursued by the Empire's sinister agents, Princess Leia races home aboard her starship, custodian of the stolen plans that can save her people and restore freedom to the galaxy...
```

How to remove it? Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the last line from a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/remove-the-last-line-from-a-file-in-bash). In short: Pipe your command through `sed '$d'`.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '$d' w | ed -s sw.diff`