# How to perform git move in Visual Studio, instead of git delete and git add, when renaming, moving files in Solution Explorer?

Tags: git, visual-studio

**Context**

I often move, rename files in Visual Studio 2022. Rename is a standard refactoring practice. However when I rename a file in Solution Explorer, not `git mv` operation is performed, instead git delete and git add.

This causes loosing the history of that particular file/class, which is a great loss in many cases.

**Question**

I can do the move operation leaving the IDE and using command line

```
git mv myoldfile.cs mynewfile.cs
```

which will keep history perfectly, but leaving the IDE is a productivity killer, especially when talking about refactoring and renaming multiple classes/files.

How to perform `git mv` within Visual Studio, instead of git delete and git add, when renaming, moving files in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Fun fact: `git` does not have a concept of "move" or "rename". Remember: a git commit is a snapshot, not a diff/delta.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling file renames in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641146/handling-file-renames-in-git)

Comment: @dai, maybe it is not clear in my question, I do know how to move files with git, (git mv) I am asking how to do this not leaving the IDE, and issue a git mv oldname.cs newname.cs I am going to edit the question

Comment: You do know that `git mv` doesn't store anything "special" or unique in your repo? [A git `mv` is identical to physically moving files yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv) or by any other tool. That's why there's no IDE support for it: because it simply isn't needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+detection

Comment: @phd many thx, that is useful. I have to rephrase my question about, why git rename detection is not working, if I move the files within the IDE. Clearly, if I use the Solution Explorer to rename the file, I ended with a separate delete and add with *loosing* history,  if I do that outside the ide, the rename detection works perfectly, and the new file has the complete history

Comment: @dai, thx, but you can not make statements about the IDE without acually experiencing it...

Comment: @dai: I was talking experience about the current and particular behaviour, not the skill. Please try it, there is a  difference between move/rename  using the solution explorer, and move/rename with git mv command. In case this statement is true, then your statement  **"That's why there's no IDE support for it: because it simply isn't needed."** is false.

Comment: @g.pickardou Visual Studio will _detect_ it as a Move only if its own heuristics say so (which are separate from `git`'s built-in move-detection logic). And there are plenty of operations in VS that trigger a filesystem move-or-rename that the Solution Explorer will show as delete-and-new and plenty that make Solution Explorer show as an actual move. If you encounter differences, blame the heuristics (which can change between individual VS releases).

Comment: @g.pickardou If you're using VS's "Refactor > Rename" then that will almost certainly be detected as a delete+new instead of a rename because there's a threshold limit (for changes to a moved/renamed file) that VS (and git) uses to determine if a file was renamed or if it thinks it's a brand new file - using Refactor Rename will most likely pass that threshold and cause it to consider it a delete+new instead of a renamed file.

Comment: that makes sense. I will conduct a more isolated experiment.

Comment: @Dai, your two comments about git move detection and the last one about refactor changes are the answer. In case you are going to post as answer I am going to accept it, otherwise probably I should delete this question

Comment: @g.pickardou I've written-up my thoughts as an answer and posted it now. I'd appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### First, let's clear-up some misconceptions...

- A `git` commit is a snapshot of your entire repo at a given point-in-time.
- A `git` commit is not a diff or changeset.
- A `git` commit does not contain any file "rename" information.
- And `git` itself does not log, monitor, record, or otherwise concern itself with files that are moved or renamed (*...at the point of creating a commit*).

The above might be counter-intuitive, or even *mind-blowing* for some people (myself included, when I first learned this) because it's contrary to all major preceding source-control systems like SVN, TFS, CSV, Perforce <sub>(Prior to Helix)</sub> and others, because all of those systems *do* store diffs or changesets and it's fundamental to their models.

<sub>Internally, `git` **does** use various forms of diffing and delta-compression, however those are intentionally hidden from the user as they're considered an implementation detail. This is because git's *domain model* is entirely built on the concept of atomic commits, which represent a snapshot state of the entire repo at a particular point-in-time. Also, uses your OS's low-level file-change-detection features to detect which specific files have been changed without needing to re-scan your entire working directory: on Linux/POSIX it uses [`lstat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/lstat.html), on Windows (where `lstat` isn't available) it uses [`fscache`](https://superuser.com/questions/974078/what-does-the-filesystem-cache-do-in-windows-7). When git computes hashes of your repo it uses [Merkel Tree structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) to avoid having to constantly recompute the hash of every file in the repo.</sub>

### So how does `git` handle moved or renamed files?

- [**It doesn't**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832963/how-can-i-control-the-rename-threshold-when-committing-files-under-git).

### ...but my `git` GUI clearly shows a file rename, not a file delete+add or edit!

- While `git` doesn't *store* information about file renames, it still is capable of *heuristically detecting* renamed files between any two git commits, as well as detecting files renamed/moved between your un-committed repo's working directory tree and your `HEAD` commit (aka "Compare with Unmodified").
- For example:

  - Consider commit "snapshot 1" with 2 files: `Foo.txt` and `Bar.txt`.
  - Then you rename `Foo.txt` to `Qux.txt` (and make no other changes).
  - Then save that as a new commit ("snapshot 2").
  - If you ask `git` to `diff` "snapshot 1" with "snapshot 2" then git can see that `Foo.txt` was renamed to `Qux.txt` (and `Bar.txt` was unchanged) because the contents (and consequently the files' cryptographic hashes) are identical, therefore it *infers* that a file rename from `Foo.txt` to `Qux.txt` occurred.

    - Fun-fact: if you ask `git` to do the same diff, but use "snapshot 2" as the *base* commit and "snapshot 1" as the subsequent commit then git will show you that it detected a rename from `Qux.txt` back to `Foo.txt`.
- **However**, if you do more than just rename or move a file between two commits, such as editing the file at the same time, then git *may-or-may-not* consider the file a new separate file instead of a renamed file.

  - This is not a bug, but a feature: this behaviour means that `git` can handle common file-system-level refactoring operations (like splitting files up) far better than file-centric source-control (like TFS and SVN) can, and you won't see refactor-related *false renames* either.
  - For example, consider a refactoring scenario where you would split a `MultipleClasses.cs` file containing multiple `class` definitions into separate `.cs` files, with one `class` per file. In this case there is no real "rename" being performed and `git`'s diff would show you 1 file being deleted (`MultipleClassesw.cs`) at the same time as the new `SingleClass1.cs`, `SingleClass2.cs`, etc files are added.

    - I imagine that you wouldn't want it to be saved to source-control history as a rename from `MultipleClasses.cs` to `SingleClass1.cs` as it would in SVN or TFS if you allowed the first rename to be saved *as* a rename in SVN/TFS.
- But, and as you can imagine, sometimes `git`'s heuristics don't work [and you need to prod it with `--follow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743739/how-to-really-show-logs-of-renamed-files-with-git) and/or [`--find-renames=<percentage>` (aka `-M<percentage>`)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Mltngt).

  - [This is explained well here](https://chelseatroy.com/2020/05/09/question-how-does-git-detect-renames/).
- My personal preferred practice is to keep your filesystem-based and edit-code-files changes in separate git commits (so a commit contains *only* edited files, or *only* added+deleted files, or *only* split-up changes), that way you make it much, much easier for git's `--follow` heuristic to detect renames/moves.

  - (This does mean that I do need to temporarily rename files back when using VS' Refactor Rename functionality, fwiw, so I can make a commit with edited files but without any renamed files).

### What does any of this have to do with Visual Studio though?

- Consider this scenario:

  - You have an existing git repo for a C# project with no pending changes (staged or otherwise). The project has a file located at `Project/Foobar.cs` containing `class Foobar`. The file is only about 1KB in size.
  - You then use Visual Studio's **Refactor > Rename...** feature to rename a `class Foobar` to `class Barfoo`.

    - Visual Studio will not-only rename `class Foobar` to `class Barfoo` *and* edit all occurrences of `Foobar` elsewhere in the project, but it will also rename `Foobar.cs` to `Barfoo.cs`.
    - In this example, the identifier `Foobar` only appears in the 1KB-sized `Foobar.cs` file two times (first in `class Foobar`, then again in the constructor definition `Foobar() {}`) so only 12 bytes (2 * 6 chars) are changed. In a 1KB file that's a 1% change (`12 / 1024 == 0.0117 --> 1.17%`).
    - `git` (and Visual Studio's built-in `git` GUI) only sees the last commit with `Foobar.cs`, and sees the current HEAD (with the uncommitted changes) has `Barfoo.cs` which is 1% different from `Foobar.cs` so it considers that a rename/move instead of a Delete+Add or an Edit, so Visual Studio's Solution Explorer will use the "Move/Rename" git status icon next to that file instead of the "File edited" or "New file" status icon.
    - However, if you make more substantial changes to `Barfoo.cs` (without committing yet) that exceed the [default change % threshold of 50%](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---find-renamesltngt) then the Solution Explorer will start showing the "New file" icon instead of "Renamed/moved file" icon.

      - And if you manually revert some of the changes to `Barfoo.cs` (again: without saving any commits yet) such that it slips below the 50% change threshold then VS's Solution Explorer will show the Rename icon again.
- A neat thing about `git` not storing *actual* file renames/moves in commits is that it means that you can safely use `git` with any software, including any software that renames/moves files! **Especially** software that is not *source-control aware*.

  - Previously, with SVN and TFS, you needed to restrict yourself to software programs that had built-in support for whatever source-control system you were using (and handled renames itself) or software that supported MSSCCI (and so saved renames via MSSCCI), otherwise you had to use a separate SVN or TFS client to save/commit your file-renames (e.g. TortoiseSvn and Team Foundation Explorer, respectively). This was a tedious and error-prone process that I'm glad to see the end of.
- Consequently, there is no need for Visual Studio (with *or without* `git` support baked-in) to inform `git` that a file was renamed/moved.

  - That's why there's no IDE support for it: because it simply isn't needed.
- The fact that a git commit isn't a delta, but a snapshot, means you can *far more easily* reorder commits, and rebase entire branches with minimal pain. This is not something that was really possible at all in SVN or TFS.

  - (After-all, how can you *meaningfully* reorder a file rename operation?)

Comment: It's a bit confusing because if you rename it and do a git status it does not tell you it's been moved like `git mv` does. But when you commit it, it does.

Comment: That's because `git mv` also stages the old and new file. If you do the rename manually and then you do `git add` on both the old and the new file(name) so the change gets staged, you _will_ see it as rename, even before committing. (The opposite is also true: If you do `git mv` but then you do `git reset` to unstage the changes, you will see an unstaged delete+add afterwards.)