# how to apply multiple git patches in one shot

Tags: git, repository

I am having around 100 patches like below,is there a way to apply all of them in one shot?

```
0001-*.patch,0002-*.patch,0003-*.patch............
```

Comment: As one commit, or as about 100 separate ones?

Comment: I want to know both ways

Answer (score 46):

You can use `git am`, for example

```
$ git am *.patch
```

For all available options, checkout the [man](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) page.

Comment: Just to clarify, would this apply all patches in one commit? Or create one commit per patch?

Comment: @TimMalone One commit per patch.

Comment: @TimMalone Even if they're all separate commits, you can always squash them after the fact via `git rebase -i`, or squash sets of commits into ranges.

Comment: Sadly, does not work!  At least, not here on Windows.

Comment: @Brad, added hack for windows.

Answer (score 9):

To get one commit for all patches:

```
git apply *.patch
git add -A
git commit -m '<your message>'
```

Patches are applied in the order of the directory listing.

[git apply](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) has most of the flags of `git am`

Answer (score 2):

On Windows/cmd `git apply` does not recognize `*`. However some parts of cmd understand it, I use below workaround:

`> for /r %i in (patch_dir\*.patch) do git apply %i`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, you can use "Git Bash" instead of "Command" . Git Bash is part of Git for Windows

Using bash (or Git bash), it is as follows:

```
cd /c/the/path/to/my/patch/files
for patch in *.patch; do git am "$patch"; done
```

Comment: I think the top-voted answer works the same way.