# git am with multiple patches

Tags: git, patch

I am trying to apply multiple patches from one git repository to another. I've created the patches with (I want the 13 latest changes):

```
cd repoA
git format-patch -13 -o ..\patch-directory
cd ..\repoB
git am ..\patch-directory\*.patch
```

This gives:

```
fatal: could not open '..\patch-directory\*.patch' for reading: Invalid argument
```

A very similar question, seem to indicate this is the correct method ([how to apply multiple git patches in one shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494750/how-to-apply-multiple-git-patches-in-one-shot)), yet it doesn't work. I can apply the patches individually, by passing the full filenames in multiple commands (and, I could easily create a script to apply them one-by-one), but, I'd like to know why this isn't working.

I am using `git version 2.9.2.windows.1`.

Comment: Did you try with an absolute path ? Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29888775/2531279

Comment: it doesn't work supplying an absolute path either, same error.

Comment: Did you try the `format-patch` with the `--relative` argument ?

Comment: Passing `--relative` to `format-patch` creates the exactly the same patches as without, and thus still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't "do" Windows so I am not sure what the next step would be, but clearly the problem is that whatever you're using as a command-line interpreter is failing to expand `*.patch` into the various patches.

Comment: I ran into the same error and was able to get it working using the Git bash that comes installed with git ([https://git-scm.com/downloads](https://git-scm.com/downloads)).

Answer (score 8):

If the shell you are using does not do whildcard expansion then you need to do this yourself or use a shell that does. The Windows shells do not so you can either use Git Bash or if you use Powershell then

```
git am (dir ..\patches\*.patch)
```

will do the expansion of the names and then pass all the expanded names as arguments to `git am`.

An alternative might be the foreach-object call (`dir ..\patches\*.patch | ForEach-Object { git am $_}`) but I would worry about this handling failed patches correctly.