# How to apply all git .patch files from /patches folder - npm

Tags: git, npm-scripts, git-patch, patch-package

**TL,DR;**

I'm looking for a git command, bash script or npm method (script) to take all `.patch` files in a folder and run

```
git apply --ignore-whitespace patches/{filename}
```

What I've tried so far:

```
git am --ignore-whitespace patches/*.patch
```

---

**Context** (what I'll use it for)

Currently working on a large project, using quite a number of libraries.  We're using webpack, frontend is Angular.js, backend on Yii2. Because devs use both linux and windows, the project is compiled inside a docker image.

Up so far, whenever we needed to make a change to a library, we forked it and specified the fork in `package.json`:

```
"package-name":"git+https://github.com/{git-user}/{package-name}"
```

and... it works.

I recently found out about an arguably better way to apply patches to modules, which is [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). In short, it avoids forking, saving the changes in a `.patch` file.

However, creating the patch file is not enough. On deployment, it also needs to be applied before building. Which translates into the following line in the deployment script:

```
docker exec -it {container-name} bash -c "git apply --ignore-whitespace patches/{package-name}+{package-version}.patch"
```

which has to run before the one running `npm run build`.

And, again, it works.

---

**Question**

I'm looking for a way to automate taking each file inside `patches/` folder and apply them, **whithout having to specify them one by one**. So that whenever a new `.patch` is pushed in the patches folder (or an existing one is modified) it gets automatically applied to the package before build, without having to change the deployment script.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494750/how-to-apply-multiple-git-patches-in-one-shot) which seems to suggest

```
git am --ignore-whitespace patches/*.patch
```

might do the trick (inside the docker console, of course). However, the [`man`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) page on `git-am` says:

> Apply a series of patches from a mailbox

What mailbox? I want to apply changes from a folder. Trying the `am` command, the console complains about not knowing who I am (wants email and password).

Do I need to treat it as a simple case of creating a bash script (`.sh` file), reading all files from the folder and running multiple `git apply` commands in a `for`?

Is there a more "git"-ish way/command of doing it?
Would it make more sense to do it using an npm script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git am` might work, but for me it complains that it can't work out what format the patch is in, presumably because it's meant for applying patches from mail.

Why not just use `git apply`?

Instead of this:

```
git am --ignore-whitespace patches/*.patch
```

do this:

```
git apply --ignore-whitespace patches/*.patch
```

Comment: You're right, I should have thought that might work. I'll try it as soon as I get to a computer. In fact, I assumed it won't work because I found the other question about it. Thank you.

Comment: Since only `.patch` files will ever make it into that folder (at least on unix systems - you never know when windows adds a `desktop.ini` :D) `git apply --ignore-whitespace patches/*` would also work. But it's safer with `.patch`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

`cat ./patches/*patch | git am`

It feeds the contents of the patch files to the `git am` command.