# How to merge multiple patches into one big patch?

Tags: git, diff, patch

I have about 20 patch files in one directory.

I need to merge them into one big patch file. I have already read multiple other questions, but combinediff can only merge 2 diffs into one one.

How can I merge all 20 patches into one?

Comment: Why not use combinediff 19 times, each time merging into the master diff?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply apply all those patches, getting 20 new commits ([`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am), which can take [multiple patches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20556774/6309)).

Then, as a case of "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164793/6309)", reset (--soft) to your original commit.
The index would be one representing the applied 20 patches.

A simple `git diff` would then generate a global patch.

A simpler approach would be to use [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) 20 times, which does not generate a commit