# How to use git-replace to replace the tree of a commit

Tags: git

I am trying to use `git replace` to rewrite history and replace the *tree* of a
commit with the tree object of a different commit. I want to make this
permanent.

The [documentation for `git replace`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace.html) seems to indicate this is
possible. I adapted the following recipe for replacing a commit from [How to
prepend the past to a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148117/3388479).

```bash
# setup a second branch with a different tree
# existing repo which already contains a few commits
git checkout master -b master2
echo "test file" > testfile.txt      # a different tree
git add testfile.txt
git commit -m "test"

# save the SHA1 of the original tree for later reference
ORIG=$(git rev-parse master^{tree})

# replace the tree of master with the one from master2
git replace master^{tree} master2^{tree}

# verify the contents of the replaced tree
git ls-tree master
```

this works, master's tree has been replaced by the one from master2, including
the extra file:

```
100644 blob 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad readme.txt
100644 blob 16b14f5da9e2fcd6f3f38cc9e584cef2f3c90ebe testfile.txt
```

However, trying to make this permanent, fails:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

yields following reply from git:

```
Rewrite e7619af3e5d424a144845c164b284875c4c20c7a (2/2)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master2' is unchanged
error: Object bc705106db90164b2e688b4b190d4358f8b09a56 is a tree, not a commit
error: Object bc705106db90164b2e688b4b190d4358f8b09a56 is a tree, not a commit
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/replace/e7a75e980c7adc0d5ab1c49ecff082b518bb6cf8^0':
  unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
WARNING: Ref 'refs/replace/e7a75e980c7adc0d5ab1c49ecff082b518bb6cf8' is unchanged
```

and after I remove the replace reference, master gets its original tree back:

```
git replace -d ${ORIG}
git ls-tree master

3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad readme.txt
```

Why does `git filter-branch` complain about the replacement and how do I do make
the replacement of the tree permanent?

P.S. I know I can do this with a `filter-branch --tree-filter` or grafts, but
(how) can I do it with `git replace`?

Comment: why would u like to do it with git replace, when there are other ways?

Comment: I think I can do it with tree-filter, but this would be a lot slower and a lot more clunky. I can do it with grafts, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800692/how-do-git-grafts-and-replace-differ-are-grafts-now-deprecated and other links suggest grafts should now be done with git replace. Ultimataly, I don't understand why git is not happy with my incantations, and I would like to understand why.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem just today. This link has some relevant information.  http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/BUG-git-filter-branch-does-not-make-tree-replacements-permanent-td7582467.html

Comment: Are you OK with rewriting the whole history?

Comment: Beware of unexpected behaviour of the `git replace sha1^{tree} sha2^{tree}`. It does replace reference to already existing tree instead of replacing the tree itself. In other words you must create the tree object before replace another tree with reference to a created one.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `git replace` is not recommended thing but if its necessary then you can do this using following steps.**

**Step1:** Go to the branch which you want to replace.

```
$ git checkout <your_branch_name>
```

**Step2:** Run the following command and get the SHA-1 of the replacement commit and replace commit. Replace commit SHA-1 you can get at the top one. And replacement commit SHA-1 is of your choice where you want to replacement of the current branch.

```
$ git log --status <your_branch_name>
```

You will get the result like:

```
$ git log --status master
commit d93378d4e774990160818038eb382f26b29f3c8f master                                                                                                
Author: rajesh <your@mail.com>                                                                                               
Date:   Tue Jul 22 19:00:15 2014 +0000                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                      
    latest commit                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                      
commit 08eb045297566d38eec5f8c2c2f987ebd7fbc2b9 master                                                                                                
Author: rajesh <your@mail.com>                                                                                               
Date:   Wed Jul 16 06:44:17 2014 +0000                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                      
    updated file1.txt                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                      
commit f4372c6c5d78eca13aa3017d72dc27f5bd38a08d master                                                                                                
Author: rajesh <your@mail.com>                                                                                               
Date:   Wed Jul 16 06:40:36 2014 +0000                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                      
    file1.txt                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                      
commit 65614018eb46c797a49cedee97653bb7716b16c2 master                                                                                                
Author: rajesh <your@mail.com>                                                                                                    
Date:   Wed Jul 16 12:03:55 2014 +0530                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                      
    Initial commit
```

**Step3:** Now run the following command to replace the current branch to replacement commit.

```
$ git replace -f d93378d4e774990160818038eb382f26b29f3c8f f4372c6c5d78eca13aa3017d72dc27f5bd38a08d
```

Step4: Now commit the things using following command.

```
$ git commit -am 'getting replaced with commit of "file1.txt"'
```

**Step5:** Now you can check that you are on the replacement commit.

Comment: What is the step 4 about? Will that be an empty commit finalizing changes made with `git replace`?

Comment: Well, step 4 is simply to commit the changes what I have done in Steps before.

Comment: @rajeshwerkushwaha, why you suggest `git replace` is not recommended thing? I haven't found any notice about it in documentation.