# Pushing branch without root to the new repository

Tags: git

Imagine I have master branch. Once new branch was created. Now I want to move exactly this branch to the new repository without comments that was commited before this branch was created.

Picture:
1. Old repository

```
newbranch    C - D - E
            /
master A - B
```

Picture: 2. New repository

```
newbranch     C - D - E
             /
master      Z
```

I don't need to move newbranch, I tried it but it took all the previous history.
I also familiar with rebase that can help me to delete commits.
But the point is there are more than 1000 commits I don't want to see in my new repo. I can't delete it manually in rebase mode.

All I need to show people only this newbranch - what was made during this branch, but not the previouses commits.

Big thanks for reply!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this new repository?  Are you creating it from scratch or how is it related to your current repo?  Squashing might work here.

Comment: I have big repo in which I made my own branch. Now I want to show what I did to other people. I don't want them to see anything else. That's why I making my own repo on bitbucket, want to push there only my branch(what exactly I did) an make permission to particilary people to watch it.

Comment: @vladimir If you can reset and redo your new repo, I have edited the answer to propose an alternative to the rebase (which had many merge conflicts): that alternative is much faster and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could at least create an orphan branch in your new repo. (`git checkout --orphan`), and make one dummy commit in it.
Or simply create a newbranch from `Z` (still in your new repo)

This assume that you have your old repo cloned locally.
And that you have created a new repo, also locally.

```
cd c:\a\path
git init create newrepo
cd newrepo.
```

First, make sure your old repo is checked out at B (ie the SHA1 representing the commit before your branch)

```
cd C:\path\to\old\repo
git checkout B
```

Then import that content into your new empty repo

```
cd C:\a\path\newrepo
git --work-tree=C:\path\to\old\repo add .
git commit -m "Import old repo as Z"
```

You can fetch your old repo in that new repo, and rebase your commits on that new branch.

```
cd C:\a\path\newrepo
git remote add oldrepo C:\path\to\old\repo
git fetch oldrepo

git checkout -b newbranch

git rebase --onto newbranch C~ oldrepo/newbranch
```

That will recreate only the commits you want in your new repo.

---

But: the rebase can be problematic, and with many [merge conflicts to be resolved manually](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/).

In your case, you could avoid that entirely with **[`git replace`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace)** or, in your case [git graft points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802005/6309), as seen [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148117/6309).
Follow the past instructions up to the `git fetch oldrepo` step, then:

```
git fetch oldrepo
git checkout -b newbranch oldrepo/newbranch
echo SHA1(C) SHA1(Z) > .git/info/grafts
```

(Replace `SHA1(xxx)` by the SHA1 of the commit `xxx`. `Z` being the new commit done in the new repo, `C` being the first commit of your `newbranch` in the old repo)

That will declare `Z` as parent commit of `C` (no merge/rebase required here).
To make that permanent, use `git filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- newbranch
rm .git/info/grafts
```

---

You can then push that new rebased branch.

```
git remote add origin /url/of/new/remote/repo

git push -u origin master
git push -u origin newbranch
```