# How to deal with git apply-mailbox conflicts when reconstructing a repo

Tags: git

I'm reconstructing a small repo from scratch in a fresh, empty git repository, using only patches (generated using `format-patch -M -B --root master`, about 180 patch files in total), and at a point during which a merge conflict occurred in the original history, the patches stop applying. I'm wondering what the rationale behind this is, and how to resolve it, either during the patch generation or application process. I've used the `--reject` option in  `git am`, and I can manually fix up the rejected hunk, but I know that there are more merge conflicts, and that manual intervention will quickly become unworkable. It seems to me that a complete patch series applied to an empty repo should introduce no conflicts or errors, but perhaps I haven't thought this through.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285699/git-how-to-create-patches-for-a-merge/2286618#2286618