# Creating patch from merge request

Tags: git, github

We have several teams merging changes to the same branch. I have to recommit selective merge requests to another branch. Is there a way to create patch from individual merge requests in git hub?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to create patches for a merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285699/git-how-to-create-patches-for-a-merge)

Comment: The link does not answer my exact problem. Can you please be specific.

Comment: Which in turn means in concrete steps:

# Perform the merge:,
git checkout master,
git merge feature,
... resolve conflicts or whatever ...
git commit,

# Format a patch:
git log -p --pretty=email --stat -m --first-parent origin/master..HEAD > feature.patch,git am feature.patch
Did you almost read the whole post?

Comment: oops missed that answer. Thanks for the help ,it answered my question.

Answer (score 15):

If you have MR url like https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/merge_requests/622/diffs you always can add just `.patch` to the end of MR link (like https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/merge_requests/622/diffs.patch ) and you will get patch :). Use accuracy because source branch can be rebased before MR is applied.
[image]

Comment: bravo! how do you found it?

Comment: I've added image above

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
 # Perform the merge:
git checkout master
git merge feature
 ... resolve conflicts or whatever ...
git commit, # Format a patch: git log -p --pretty=email --stat -m --first-parent origin/master..HEAD > feature.patch
git am feature.patch
```

From:

[Git: How to create patches for a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285699/git-how-to-create-patches-for-a-merge)